# Google Maps inside iframe not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I ran into a strange issue, and I don't know what the problem is. The following jQuery code is a simplified version of what I want to achieve:

```
var iframe = $('<iframe />');
iframe.prop('src', 'https://maps.google.com/maps?q=London&hl=en&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=46.677964,93.076172&t=h&hnear=London,+United+Kingdom&z=10');
iframe.appendTo($('body')); 

// When the iframe loads:
iframe.load(function() {
    alert(1);
});
```

The map is never loaded, and the `load()` event is never triggered. Chrome reports the following error:

`Refused to display 'https://maps.google.com/maps?q=London&hl=en&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=46.677964,93.076172&t=h&hnear=London,+United+Kingdom&z=10' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

How does one bypass this?

Here's a [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RLuYw/).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Appending `&output=embed` to the end of the URL fixes the problem.

**Update**: Google disabled this feature, which was working at the time the answer was originally posted. This solution no longer works.

Comment: @pomarc that doesn't warrant a downvote. When the answer was posted more than a year ago, this was valid. Please consider rescinding your harsh downvote...

Comment: Even in 2020, the output=embed trick still works in practice. I'm using it right now and it's working.

Comment: I can confirm that in Nov 2020 output=embed is no longer working.

Answer (score 22):

As of 2014, the option `&output=embed` does not work anymore. Google suggests you to switch to Google Maps Embed API. Here is a [Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start).

Basically, the new iframe link is:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key={BROWSER_KEY}&q={YOUR_ADDRESS_ENCODED}
```

Remember to enable **Google Maps Embed API** in API Console.

*p.s. checked working at the moment I write this answer*

Comment: Does not work for me with `/dir` directions (not `/place`)

Comment: Hi @kaiser , following the setup wizard [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start), the the last piece of URL should be `/directions` instead of `/dir`

Comment: I don't understand this logic (Google's, not yours). Do I *have* to have a Google Developers account now in order to embed-share a map?

Comment: Yes @WoodrowShigeru .

Comment: Why? Google Developers Account is free.

Comment: @WoodrowShigeru yeah, so they can have your data and spam you with products offers...gosh they are doing this to my customers, it's a living hell...

Comment: I am using a Javascript/Jquery pretty photo slider to show some pictures. After 6 pictures, I am showing a 7th picture of the google map, clicking on which should show the Google map in a popup. I am getting the same error as the original user. If I change the URL in https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=42.579895%2C-88.46074&markers=42.579895%2C-88.46074&zoom=17&maptype=roadmap&iframe=true&height=600&key=xxx to www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key={BROWSER_KEY}&q={YOUR_ADDRESS_ENCODED} will it show the maps in a popup? Do I have to enable Google Maps Embed API ?

Comment: @MarceloAgimóvel It's a completely free map service in return for an email address. Seems like a fair price

Comment: @Chuck Le Butt Google also offers free email addresses in return for the time it takes to fill out a form. Pairs well with the free maps service.

Answer (score 17):

Make sure you enable the google maps embed api in addition to places API.

Generate you map from here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start

Comment: This solution works now, please change the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it was very unclear why. Turns out I had a space in the embed src url...
So instead of `https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Sydney,Australia&key=<myKey>` I was building the string in PHP and had a newline character in the string accidentally

```
$apiKey = 'mySecretKey';
return 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place 
?q=Sydney,Australia&key='.$apiKey;
```

I solved it by concatenating the strings instead

```
$apiKey = 'mySecretKey';
return 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place'.
'?q=Sydney,Australia&key='.$apiKey;
```

Answer (score -1):

I came across this issue today, and found that it was a single chrome extension that was blocking the map from loading for me.

My solution was to disable all extensions, then enable them one-by-one to see which (if any) were causing the issue.

Your chrome extensions can be found here: chrome://extensions/

Answer (score -2):

> ```
> I've run this:
> ```

```
      <head>
        <title>Top Secret Route</title>
      </head>
      <div>
        <div>
          <embed width="1000px" height="1000px" frameborder="3px" style="border: 0px" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/directions?Moscow&destination=StBasil,Moscow&key=API-KEY">
          <button onclick="<embed>" ondbclick="<div>">embed</button>
          </embed>
        </div>

      </html>
```

> but it refused to connect
> It refused even when I put it into CodePen

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31324110)