# Get google map link with latitude/longitude

Tags: google-maps

I want to get google map link that show title/content in  marker that located at latitude/longitude.

so parameters are title, content, latitude , longitude .
Result is a link like this
https://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&ll=xxx,xxx&title=xxx&content=xxx

I searched google and don't find answer, event in google API.

Comment: Do u want link or html code?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

I've tried doing the request you need using an iframe to show the result for latitude, longitude, and zoom needed:

```
<iframe 
  width="300" 
  height="170" 
  frameborder="0" 
  scrolling="no" 
  marginheight="0" 
  marginwidth="0" 
  src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q='+YOUR_LAT+','+YOUR_LON+'&hl=es&z=14&amp;output=embed"
 >
 </iframe>
 <br />
 <small>
   <a 
    href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q='+data.lat+','+data.lon+'&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed" 
    style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left" 
    target="_blank"
   >
     See map bigger
   </a>
 </small>
```

Comment: Thanks @CroiOS!! Great to know that my answer worked for you. @jziwenchen will have to decide to tick my answer as the good one ;)

Comment: thanks for helping but what does it mean ? hl=es;z=14

Comment: @aynaz, "es" is spanish language and "z" is the zoom that will have the map

Comment: @vignesh try without quote <iframe src = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=10.305385,77.923029&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe>

Comment: it don't show the title. So it should not be accepted. Still looking for that.
The link looks like this: 
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOURKEY&q=LAT,LON

But searching for an additional Marker setup like &title=Cool Place

Comment: There's a typo in this answer. It should be `&z=14` instead of `;z=14`

Comment: The question is asked specifically for combination of (lat,lng + Title) we pass.. where is the title in this answer? otherwise, this example is there in google's api guide.

Comment: It still works, just remove the ' before and after the long lat.

Comment: I dunno how it worked for all of you guys but I was getting errors even with the above solution. Just figured out that you need `&`instead of `;` right before `output=embed`. So an example src would be: ``https://www.google.com/maps?q=52.527995,13.302482&hl=es;z%3D14&amp&output=embed ``

Comment: changing the &amp; to & made this work for me

Answer (score 28):

@vignesh the single quotes are only needed if you are using js variables

```html
<iframe src = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=10.305385,77.923029&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 11):

None of the above answers work, but this will.

```
<iframe src="'https://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + lat + ',' + lng + '&t=&z=15&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed'" />
```

Answer (score 4):

See documentation on how to search using latitude/longitude [here](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=18539).

For location specified as: +38° 34' 24.00", -109° 32' 57.00

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=%2B38%C2%B0+34'+24.00%22,+-109%C2%B0+32'+57.00&ie=UTF-8
```

Note that the plus signs (%2B) and degree symbols(%C2%B0) need to be properly encoded.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it in iframe, dynamically bind data from object.

"https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=[APIKEY]%20&q=" + content..Latitude + ',' + content.Longitude;

References for longitude and Latitude.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide

Note:[APIKEY] will expire in 60days and regenerate key.

[[image]google-maps](/questions/tagged/google-maps) [google-maps-embed](/questions/tagged/google-maps-embed)

Answer (score 1):

Use View mode returns a map with no markers or directions.

The example below uses the optional maptype parameter to display a satellite view of the map.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view
  ?key=YOUR_API_KEY
  &center=-33.8569,151.2152
  &zoom=18
  &maptype=satellite
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggested answer no longer works after 2014. Now you have to use Google Maps Embed API for loading into iframe.

Here is [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388897/google-maps-inside-iframe-not-loading) for the question and solution.

If you are using Angular like me you won't be able to load the google maps in iframe because of XSS security issue. For that you need to sanitise the URL with **Pipe** from angular.

Here is [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52746741/4728835) to do so.

All the suggestions are tested and works 100% as of today.

Answer (score -1):

```
  <iframe src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q='+YOUR_LAT+','+YOUR_LON+'&hl=en&z=14&amp;output=embed" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

put your replace lattitude,longitude values on YOUR_LAT,YOUR_LON respectively.
hl parameter for setting language on map, z for zoomlevel;