# <img>: Unsafe value used in a resource URL context

Tags: angular

Since upgrading to the latest Angular 2 release candidate, my `img` tags:

```html
<img class='photo-img' [hidden]="!showPhoto1" src='{{theMediaItem.photoURL1}}'>
```

are throwing a browser error:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context

The value of the url is:

```
http://veeu-images.s3.amazonaws.com/media/userphotos/116_1464645173408_cdv_photo_007.jpg
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried the suggestion made in the other solution that this question is supposed to be a duplicate of but I am getting the same error.

I have added the following code to the controller:

```js
import {DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/veeu/veeu.html'
})
export class VeeUPage {
  static get parameters() {
    return [[NavController], [App], [MenuController], [DomSanitizationService]];
  }

  constructor(nav, app, menu, sanitizer) {

    this.app = app;
    this.nav = nav;
    this.menu = menu;
    this.sanitizer = sanitizer;

    this.theMediaItem.photoURL1 = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.mediaItems[1].url);
  }
```

I am still getting the same error message.

**EDIT2:**

I have also changed the html to:

```html
<img class='photo-img' [hidden]="!showPhoto1" [src]='theMediaItem.photoURL1'>
```

I still get the same error message

Comment: I am not clear on what I should change. Do I change src="{{something.else}}" to [src]="something.else"?

Comment: Exactly: `[src]='theMediaItem.photoURL1'`

Comment: Yes I tried that and I get the same error message.

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using?

Comment: I think I am using 2.0.0-beta.15 (I am using ionic and not altogether sure how to check)

Apologies for the way I have added code I am not clear on the protocol.

Comment: Just use the `[{}]` button instead of the `[<>]`. The later is for runnable code (HTML+JS)

Comment: Google didn't find any other mention of the error message except in Angular2 sources at
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service.ts#L131 and that is part of the sanitization added in RC.1. Are you sure you don't linke to any RCx sources?

Comment: How would I check if I am linking to RCx resources?

Comment: For latest RC, RC.5 and RC.6 check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037760/how-to-set-iframe-src-in-angular-2-without-causing-unsafe-value-exception

Comment: This resolved the issue for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39859867/6046296

Answer (score 123, accepted):

I'm using rc.4 and this method works for ES2015(ES6):

```
import {DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/veeu/veeu.html'
})
export class VeeUPage {
  static get parameters() {
    return [NavController, App, MenuController, DomSanitizationService];
  }

  constructor(nav, app, menu, sanitizer) {

    this.app = app;
    this.nav = nav;
    this.menu = menu;
    this.sanitizer = sanitizer;    
  }

  photoURL() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.mediaItems[1].url);
  }
}
```

In the HTML:

```
<iframe [src]='photoURL()' width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"
    webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Using a function will ensure that the value doesn't change after you sanitize it. Also be aware that the sanitization function you use depends on the context.

**For images, `bypassSecurityTrustUrl` will work but for other uses you need to refer to the documentation**:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html

Comment: What is "rc4" (and later [Helzgate refers to RC3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38079724/1175496) ) ? I mean, how do I map that to a github version?  In both github and npm I only see versions like 2.4.4 or 2.4.5. I'm currently on 2.4.4 and it seems the DomSanitizer changed ; so this is the import you need: `import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';`

Comment: Oh, I think [angular's github](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/2.0.0-rc.3/modules)  **branches** will refer to `2.4.x` for example, but github **tags** will refer to release candidates, like `2.0.0-rc3`. And I can see [in rc3](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.3/modules/%40angular/platform-browser/index.ts), for example the class was still named `DomSanitizationService`.

Comment: `this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)` for videos

Comment: Read the documentation carefully before using this: **bypassSecurityTrustUrl()** **WARNING:** *calling this method with untrusted user data exposes your application to XSS security risks!* Seems to me that it is not safe to do so, unless you are really sure about the image source being trusted. Even if it comes from a server, if it was uploaded by a user it would be possible to exploit such a solution.

Comment: Don't use src="{{photoUrl()}}" as this still throws the exception  so [src]="photoUrl()" does the trick.

Answer (score 222):

## Pipe

```ts
    // Angular
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    
    /**
     * Sanitize HTML
     */
    @Pipe({
      name: 'safe'
    })
    export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
      /**
       * Pipe Constructor
       *
       * @param _sanitizer: DomSanitezer
       */
      // tslint:disable-next-line
      constructor(protected _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
      }
    
      /**
       * Transform
       *
       * @param value: string
       * @param type: string
       */
      transform(value: string, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
        switch (type) {
          case 'html':
            return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
          case 'style':
            return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
          case 'script':
            return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
          case 'url':
            return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
          case 'resourceUrl':
            return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
          default:
            return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
        }
      }
    }
```

### Template

```
{{ data.url | safe:'url' }}
```

### That's it!

##### Note: You shouldn't need it but here is the component use of the pipe

```ts
      // Public properties
      itsSafe: SafeHtml;

      // Private properties
      private safePipe: SafePipe = new SafePipe(this.domSanitizer);
    
      /**
       * Component constructor
       *
       * @param safePipe: SafeHtml
       * @param domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
       */
      constructor(private safePipe: SafePipe, private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
      }
    
      /**
       * On init
       */
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.itsSafe = this.safePipe.transform('<h1>Hi</h1>', 'html');
      }
```

Answer (score 63):

**The most elegant way to fix this:** use pipe. [Here is example (my blog).](https://filipmolcik.com/error-unsafe-value-used-in-a-resource-url-context/) So you can then simply use `url | safe` pipe to bypass the security.

```
<iframe [src]="url | safe"></iframe>
```

Refer to the documentation on npm for details: https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-pipe

Comment: This is an easy solution. Thanks.

Comment: It has some new usage syntax. Its available on its npmjs url.

Comment: Yes, new usage is e.g. for URLs: <iframe [src]="url | safe: 'url'"></iframe>

Comment: so thank you. you saved my day.

Answer (score 48):

Use Safe Pipe to fix it.

- Create a safe pipe if u haven't any.

  `ng g pipe safe`
- add Safe pipe in app.module.ts

  `declarations: [SafePipe]`
- declare safe pipe in your ts

Import Dom Sanitizer and Safe Pipe to access url safely

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })

export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
transform(url) {
 return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```

- Add safe with src url

  <img width="900" height="500" [src]="link | safe"/>

Comment: Great! One thing, shouldn't it be 'ng g pipe safe' instead of 'ng g c pipe safe', what obviously won't work?

Answer (score 21):

Either you can expose sanitizer to the view, or expose a method that forwards the call to bypassSecurityTrustUrl

```
<img class='photo-img' [hidden]="!showPhoto1" 
    [src]='sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(theMediaItem.photoURL1)'>
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that we can make methods public in the constructor and consume them in them template.

Answer (score 11):

Angular treats all values as untrusted by default. When a value is inserted into the DOM from a template, via property, attribute, style, class binding, or interpolation, Angular sanitizes and escapes untrusted values.

So if you are manipulating DOM directly and inserting content in it, you need to sanitize it, otherwise Angular will throw errors.

I have created the pipe **SanitizeUrlPipe** for this

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Pipe({
    name: "sanitizeUrl"
})
export class SanitizeUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

    transform(v: string): SafeHtml {
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(v);
    }
}
```

and this is how you can use

```
<iframe [src]="url | sanitizeUrl" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

If you want to add HTML, then **SanitizeHtmlPipe** can help

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Pipe({
    name: "sanitizeHtml"
})
export class SanitizeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

    transform(v: string): SafeHtml {
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(v);
    }
}
```

Read more about angular security [here](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-security-the-domsanitizer-service-2202c83bd90).

Comment: "So if you are manipulating DOM directly and inserting content in it, you need to sanitize it, otherwise Angular will throw errors." But you're not sanitising in your pipe, you're bypassing sanitisation.

Answer (score 4):

> I usually add separate `safe pipe` reusable component as following

```
# Add Safe Pipe

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({name: 'mySafe'})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    }

    public transform(url) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    }
}
```

```html
# then create shared pipe module as following 

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { SafePipe } from './safe.pipe';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        SafePipe
    ],
    exports: [
        SafePipe
    ]
})
export class SharedPipesModule {
}
```

```html
# import shared pipe module in your native module

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        SharedPipesModule,
    ],
})
export class SupportModule {
}
```

```html
<!-------------------
call your url (`trustedUrl` for me) and add `mySafe` as defined in Safe Pipe
---------------->
<div class="container-fluid" *ngIf="trustedUrl">
    <iframe [src]="trustedUrl | mySafe" align="middle" width="100%" height="800" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import {DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Component({
 templateUrl: 'build/pages/veeu/veeu.html'
 })
  export class VeeUPage {
     trustedURL:any;
      static get parameters() {
               return [NavController, App, MenuController, 
              DomSanitizationService];
        }
      constructor(nav, app, menu, sanitizer) {
        this.app = app;
        this.nav = nav;
        this.menu = menu;
        this.sanitizer = sanitizer;  
        this.trustedURL  = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.mediaItems[1].url);
        } 
 }



 <iframe [src]='trustedURL' width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"
   webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
</iframe>


User property binding instead of function.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better and tested safe pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
import {
  DomSanitizer,
  SafeHtml,
  SafeResourceUrl,
  SafeScript,
  SafeStyle,
  SafeUrl,
  SafeValue,
} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe',
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private readonly domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(
    value: string | undefined,
    type: string,
    bypass: boolean
  ):
    | SafeHtml
    | SafeStyle
    | SafeScript
    | SafeUrl
    | SafeResourceUrl
    | SafeValue
    | null {
    if (!value) {
      return null;
    }
    switch (type) {
      case 'style':
        return bypass
          ? this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value)
          : this.domSanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.STYLE, value);
      case 'script':
        return bypass
          ? this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value)
          : this.domSanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.SCRIPT, value);
      case 'url':
        return bypass
          ? this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value)
          : this.domSanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL, value);
      case 'resourceUrl':
        return bypass
          ? this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value)
          : this.domSanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.RESOURCE_URL, value);
      default:
        return bypass
          ? this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value)
          : this.domSanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, value);
    }
  }
}



import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { SafePipe } from './safe.pipe';

const mockDomSanitizer = ({
  sanitize: jest.fn(),
  bypassSecurityTrustHtml: jest.fn(),
  bypassSecurityTrustStyle: jest.fn(),
  bypassSecurityTrustUrl: jest.fn(),
  bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl: jest.fn(),
  bypassSecurityTrustScript: jest.fn(),
} as unknown) as DomSanitizer;

describe('SafePipe', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  it('should return null value when value received is undefined', () => {
    const pipe = new SafePipe(mockDomSanitizer);
    expect(pipe.transform(undefined, 'style', true)).toBeNull();
  });
  test.each([
    { a: 'style', b: true, expected: 'bypassSecurityTrustStyle' },
    { a: 'script', b: true, expected: 'bypassSecurityTrustScript' },
    { a: 'url', b: true, expected: 'bypassSecurityTrustUrl' },
    { a: 'resourceUrl', b: true, expected: 'bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl' },
    { a: 'html', b: true, expected: 'bypassSecurityTrustHtml' },
  ])('should call the correspondent method', ({ a, b, expected }) => {
    const pipe = new SafePipe(mockDomSanitizer);
    pipe.transform('value', a, b);
    const domSanitizer = mockDomSanitizer as never;
    expect(domSanitizer[expected]).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  test.each([
    { a: 'style', b: false, expected: 'sanitize' },
    { a: 'script', b: false, expected: 'sanitize' },
    { a: 'url', b: false, expected: 'sanitize' },
    { a: 'resourceUrl', b: false, expected: 'sanitize' },
    { a: 'html', b: false, expected: 'sanitize' },
  ])('should call the correspondent method', ({ a, b, expected }) => {
    const pipe = new SafePipe(mockDomSanitizer);
    pipe.transform('value', a, b);
    const domSanitizer = mockDomSanitizer as never;
    expect(domSanitizer[expected]).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set image as background image to avoid `unsafe url` error:

```
<div [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + imageUrl + ')'" class="show-image"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.show-image {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: cover;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img class='photo-img' [hidden]="!showPhoto1" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{theMediaItem.photoURL1}}">
```