# How to set <iframe src="..."> without causing `unsafe value` exception?

Tags: angular

I am working on a tutorial involving the setting of an `iframe` `src` attribute:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="{{video.url}}"></iframe>
```

This throws an exception:

```
Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context
at DomSanitizationServiceImpl.sanitize...
```

I have already tried using bindings with `[src]` with no success.

Answer (score 439, accepted):

**Update v8**

Below answers work but [exposes your application to XSS security risks!](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-security-the-domsanitizer-service-2202c83bd90).
Instead of using `this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)`, it is recommended to use `this.domSanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL, url)`

**Update**

For **RC.6^** version use **DomSanitizer**

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Uifk3dxf7vwKJsUFb0d9?p=preview)**

And a good option is using pure pipe for that:

```typescript
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(url) {
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```

remember to add your new `SafePipe` to the `declarations` array of the AppModule. ([as seen on documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html))

```typescript
@NgModule({
   declarations : [
     ...
     SafePipe
   ],
})
```

html

```typescript
<iframe width="100%" height="300" [src]="url | safe"></iframe>
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9JPA5r0gjTwfVckohihp?p=preview)**

If you use `embed` tag this might be interesting for you:

- [how with angular2 rc.6 disable sanitize on embed html tag which display pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393431/how-with-angular2-rc-6-disable-sanitize-on-embed-html-tag-which-display-pdf/39394814#39394814)

---

**Old version RC.5**

You can leverage `DomSanitizationService` like this:

```typescript
export class YourComponent {
  url: SafeResourceUrl;
  constructor(domSanitizationService: DomSanitizationService) {
    this.url = domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('your url');
  }
}
```

And then bind to `url` in your template:

```typescript
<iframe width="100%" height="300" [src]="url"></iframe>
```

Don't forget to add the following imports:

```typescript
import { SafeResourceUrl, DomSanitizationService } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

**[Plunker sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZJBXJVL4LhD41R8VE0jj?p=preview)**

Comment: Old version worked for me as of today, not sure what "old' is referring to as I am using Ionic 2 and DomSanitizer was not even recognized (whereas DomSanitizationService was). Thanks!

Comment: @FugueWeb That's because ionic2 is using angular RC4 today. https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta11-2016-08-05

Comment: I am using Ionic2. I declare a pipe `Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(url): any {
 return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
  
} ` and in template I call `<iframe width="100%" height="315" src="{{url}} | safe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`. But it doesn't work with error 'unsafe value'. Please help

Comment: @Insane Rose what version ionic2 do you use?

Comment: @yurzui I use 2.1.0 When I call `[src]="'https://www.youtube.com/embed/CM6rVEAAQ3k' | safe" ` It works normally. But if ` [src]="{{url}} | safe" ` with url='link youtube' . It doesn't work. I can't see

Comment: @Insane Rose i guess it should be `[src]="url | safe"` Just remove brackets

Comment: > Angular 2.2.1

```
constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.url = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('your url here');
  }
```

Comment: I would like to add that not all webapps are iframe friendly and any errors that say that X-Frame-Headers is `sameorigin` mean that the webapp does not want to be embedded as an iframe and are not an issue with angular2.

Comment: Interestingly I was able to embed my YouTube video iframe today with no issues (ie. I did not need this solution) - I am using ng4. A bit off topic but if you want a responsive video width here is a great solution - https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Comment: @yurzui  I followed your recommendation for the updated v8. However when I use `this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL, url)` I'm getting an error "ERROR Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context"   I I change it to `this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)` works fine. Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: `this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL, url)` doesn't work and `this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)` works but raises high security vulnerability issue in static code analysis, which prevents me from moving this to production. Need a way to fix this

Comment: Doing `this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL, url)` alone doesn't work it seems, so what I do is call `sanitize` and then `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` on the result, unsure if that's a good way to do it but that works at least and seems safe enough.

Comment: Your plunker has a case mismatch in pdfURL/pdfUrl identifiers.

Comment: this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url) that makes the code vulnerable and i can not move it to production. Any better approach for this?

Comment: I was assigning the src wrongly like src="url | safe" so it was not working and corrected it to [src]="url | safe", then the iframe in teh component started displaying the url. Thanks.

Comment: @Mohit  did you find the way to resolve the code vulnerable

Comment: @zhangjianrencai - actually i have used the same code, in production we have https so it won't cause any issue

Comment: @yurzui May I know what is the issue with using `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` method?

Comment: what if I've an empty src in the load of the component, as the data is dinamically charged by workflow of the user?

Comment: Joining the party late, but the chrome issue with embed tag is not only limited to chrome, it is in edge also

Answer (score 42):

This one works for me.

```js
import { Component,Input,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer,SafeResourceUrl,} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'player',
    templateUrl: './player.component.html',
    styleUrls:['./player.component.scss'],
    
})
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit{
    @Input()
    id:string; 
    url: SafeResourceUrl;
    constructor (public sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.id);      
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach works for me since I use this in 1 place. Otherwise the pipe approach is better.

Comment: @Pang How it work? i have the same issue i want to add my parameter in url i am using these code "@Input()
  parameterForFB: number = this.selectedStudent.schoolId
  url: string = "http://designs.mydeievents.com/jq-3d-flip-book/index.html?id=${parameterForFB}";
  urlSafe: SafeResourceUrl;" but not working face issue in parameter.

Comment: Thank you. This is the only way I could get this to work, none of the examples with pipe worked.

Answer (score 31):

This works me to Angular 5.2.0

**fileName.Component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample',
  templateUrl: './fileName.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fileName.component.scss']
})

export class FileName implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  url: string = "https://www.mmlpqtpkasjdashdjahd.com";
  urlSafe: SafeResourceUrl;

  constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.urlSafe= this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);
  }

}
```

**fileName.Component.html**

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0" [src]="urlSafe"></iframe>
```

thats all folks!!!

Comment: Tried this. It works but the console keeps throwing the error
Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context

Comment: urlSafe can be defined as follows.

urlSafe: SafeResourceUrl | undefined;
urlSafe!: SafeResourceUrl;

Answer (score 8):

All answers seem wrong to be honest. Using `this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)` only bypasses the security and treats the url as a `SafeResourceUrl`. However, given url may still be malicious resulting in security violations. Docs say so too: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl

A solution would be to call `sanitizer` first and the pass the `sanitizer` return value to the `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` like this:

`this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL, url))`

This way you sanitize any malicious code and then bypass the security denoting this is indeed a safe url.

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me (tested with angular 13).

Answer (score 7):

```
constructor(
 public sanitizer: DomSanitizer, ) {

 }
```

I had been struggling for 4 hours. the problem was in img tag. When you use square bracket to 'src' ex: [src]. you can not use this angular expression {{}}. you just give directly from an object example below. if you give angular expression {{}}. you will get interpolation error.

1. first i used ngFor to iterate the countries

   ```
   *ngFor="let country of countries"
   ```
2. second you put this in the img tag. this is it.

   ```
   <img [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(country.flag)"
   height="20" width="20" alt=""/>
   ```

Comment: Be aware that putting function call inside HTML is a bad idea because it is gonna be called everytime ChangeDetector will check for changes.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue as well, but in order to use a safe pipe in my angular module, I installed the safe-pipe npm package, which you can find [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-pipe). FYI, this worked in Angular 9.1.3, I haven't tried this in any other versions of Angular. Here's how you add it step by step:

1. Install the package via npm install safe-pipe or yarn add safe-pipe. This will store a reference to it in your dependencies in the package.json file, which you should already have from starting a new Angular project.
2. Add SafePipeModule module to NgModule.imports in your Angular module file like so:

   ```
   import { SafePipeModule } from 'safe-pipe';

   @NgModule({
       imports: [ SafePipeModule ]
   })
   export class AppModule { }
   ```
3. Add the safe pipe to an element in the template for the Angular component you are importing into your NgModule this way:

```
<element [property]="value | safe: sanitizationType"></element>
```

4. Here are some specific examples of the safePipe in an html element:

```
<div [style.background-image]="'url(' + pictureUrl + ')' | safe: 'style'" class="pic bg-pic"></div>
<img [src]="pictureUrl | safe: 'url'" class="pic" alt="Logo">
<iframe [src]="catVideoEmbed | safe: 'resourceUrl'" width="640" height="390"></iframe>
<pre [innerHTML]="htmlContent | safe: 'html'"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

I defined an id in the iframe

```html
<iframe id="embeddedPage"></iframe>
```

and in the component I used this code

```js
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
    
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const iframe =  document.getElementById('embeddedPage') as HTMLIFrameElement;
    iframe.contentWindow.location.replace('your url');
  }

}
```

Comment: WARNING: This "works" because it bypasses Angular's checks / awareness, point being this is still insecure if the `url` can't be trusted

Answer (score 1):

**Update V13**

the url should be sanitized first, then once we know its safe
we can use bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl.

```
constructor(
  private readonly domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

sanitize(){
url = this.domSanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL, `/test`); //sanitize first
this.url = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);//then bypass
}
```

Then bind the url in your template.

```
<iframe #iFrame [src]="url">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll share this solution even if this is NOT best practice, but it happened to me once that we were not allowed to use the `this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)` solution because of an automatic security warning that stopped the CI/CD pipelines.

```
@Component({
  template: '<iframe #iframeRef></iframe>'
})
export class UnsafeUrlBypassIframeSampleComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('iframeRef') iframe: ElementRef<HTMLIFrameElement>;
  
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}
  
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const MY_UNSAFE_URL = '/path/to/something';
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.iframe.nativeElement, 'src', MY_UNSAFE_URL);
  }
}
```

If it is the case that you need to bypass Angular security systems, and this will inevitably lead to vulnerabilities, it is best to do it explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

> I usually add separate safe pipe reusable component as following

```
# Add Safe Pipe

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({name: 'mySafe'})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    }

    public transform(url) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    }
}
```

```html
# then create shared pipe module as following 

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { SafePipe } from './safe.pipe';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        SafePipe
    ],
    exports: [
        SafePipe
    ]
})
export class SharedPipesModule {
}
```

```html
# import shared pipe module in your native module

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        SharedPipesModule,
    ],
})
export class SupportModule {
}
```

```html
<!-------------------
call your url (`trustedUrl` for me) and add `mySafe` as defined in Safe Pipe
---------------->
<div class="container-fluid" *ngIf="trustedUrl">
    <iframe [src]="trustedUrl | mySafe" align="middle" width="100%" height="800" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score -9):

Congratulation ! ¨^^
I have an easy & efficient solution for you, yes!

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" [attr.src]="video.url"></iframe
```

> [attr.src] instead of src
>   "video.url" and not {{video.url}}

Great ;)

Comment: That doesn't make a difference for string values.

Comment: it doesn't work. Getting error message `unsafe value used in a resource URL context`

Comment: So, you can use the html5 video tag, but if you insist to use iframe (for many reasons;) see other solutions that use DomSanitizationService..

Comment: so if you are looking for using the 'video' tag , it will be like this   `<video>
              <source [src]=video.url  type="video/mp4" />
               Browser not supported
            </video>`  _in fact, you can use it inorder to desplay documents too .._ if you have any troubles when using video tag, I'm here ;)