# DomSanitizationService is not a function

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-services

As people always say there is no question called a dumb question.

I am learning Angular 2.0 following the official tutorial now. It is using rc2.0 as I can see from the packageconfig file. I was trying to suppress the frame work complaining the "Unsafe" url in the iFrame tag.

I have checked the instructions from this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037760/how-to-set-iframe-src-in-angular-2-without-causing-unsafe-value-exception)
and followed everything that's been shown in the LIVE Plunker.

My VS Code doesn't complain anything in the compile time but from the Chrome inspector I can see the error.

[image]

Following are the TS file of my project.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute }       from '@angular/router';
import { ParcelsService } from './parcels.service';
import { SafeResourceUrl, DomSanitizationService } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Parcel } from './mock-parcels';
@Component({
  template: `
  <h2>Parcels</h2>
  <div *ngIf="parcel">
    <h3>"{{parcel.checkUrl}}"</h3>
    <iframe width=800 height=500 src="{{safeUrl}}}"></iframe>

    <p>
      <button (click)="gotoHeroes()">Back</button>
    </p>
  </div>
  `,
  providers:[ParcelsService, DomSanitizationService]
})
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {
  parcel: Parcel;
  safeUrl : SafeResourceUrl;
  private sub: any;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private service: ParcelsService,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizationService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       let id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
       this.parcel = this.service.getParcel(id);
     });
     this.safeUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.parcel.checkUrl);

  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
  gotoHeroes() { this.router.navigate(['/heroes']); }
}
```

Has anyone ever come across similar issue? Please help to find what I have done wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to import and provide the `BROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS`:

```
import { BROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS, 
         SafeResourceUrl, 
         DomSanitizationService } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

and in your `providers` array:

```
providers: [ParcelsService, BROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS]
```

---

> **UPDATE**: for the final release things changed a little

```
import { __platform_browser_private__, 
         SafeResourceUrl, 
         DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

and add it to the providers like so:

```
providers: [ParcelsService, __platform_browser_private__, BROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS]
```

---

> **UPDATE FOR ANGULAR 4+**: since Angular 4, there's some changes:

Now, you don't have to pass `DomSanitizer` to `providers`. You can import directly in your component and grab it in the component's `constructor`. Same goes for `SafeResourceUrl`.

Also:

- `__platform_browser_private__` is no longer in `@angular/platform-browser`.
- `BROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS` is no longer in `@angular/platform-browser`. It is now implemented [as a provider] into `BrowserModule` which can be imported from `@angular/platform-browser`.
- P.S. `BrowserModule` is usually added into your `app.module`
  module's imports array.

Answer (score 1):

Update for Angular 7:  The export has been renamed   eBROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS in angular/platform-browser/src/private_export.d.ts