# Click from controller HTML Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

How i can run function from string in controller in Ionic 2. My code:

```
export class ProjectsPage {

    text:string = '' ;

    constructor() {
        this.text = '<a (click)="myAlert()">Show allert</a>' ;
    }

    myAlert() {
        alert(1) ;
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you show `this.text` in template?

Comment: I updated the answer. Check it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using `DomSanitizationService`. Import the service

```
import {DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Now, in class constructor do this

```
  constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizationService) {
      this.text = '<a (click)="myAlert()">Show allert</a>' ;
      this.text = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.text);
  }
```

Use like this in template

```
<div [innerHTML]="text"></div>  // here the DOM will be appended
```

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38353549/6554634) to follow up the updates in the release versions and imports

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess what you are asking for, but your mistake is most likely caused by passing string in `(click)` function. Change is to:

```
 this.text = '<a (click)="'+this.myAlert()+'">Show allert</a>' ;
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: `Error: Cannot find name 'myAlert'` If i set `this.myAlert()` emulator is hangs

Comment: how about '<a (click)="'+this.myAlert()+'">Show allert</a>' ?

Comment: if `(click)="'+this.myAlert()+'"` then function cyclically runing on page init