# how with angular2 rc.6 disable sanitize on embed html tag which display pdf

Tags: angular

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong here:

Template:

```
<embed [src]="pdfUrl" width="500" height="100%" type='application/pdf'>
```

Class:

```
pdfURL;
constructor(private domSanitizer : DomSanitizer) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.pdfUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('http://example.com/pdf.pdf')
}
```

This does not actually load the `<embed>` but doesn't throw an error.

I tried it using `SafeUrl` type on `pdfURL` and with `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl()`.
The `<embed>` tag receives the right url but nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 10):

I quess it should be:

```
this.pdfUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('url')
```

and use it like:

```
<iframe [src]="pdfUrl" width="500" height="600" type='application/pdf'></iframe>
```

See **[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Uifk3dxf7vwKJsUFb0d9?p=preview)**

**Update**(There is a bug with `embed` tag in Chrome)

For `embed` tag you can reinject embed tag via `outerHTML`:

```
this.renderer.setElementProperty(el, 'outerHTML', el.outerHTML)
```

See **[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fveyLHSLgdgLFbQcwEek?p=preview)** for this case

Comment: Thanks to this workaround but still not working, maybe this directive is not working as I need... Because I need change url dynamically so check this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/k3iJ84ZjRCj1mJVRAy29?p=preview you can check this not working when I change pdf after 3seconds, I want in same place modify a lot of times src (still blank)

PS: I dont' understand in this second plunker you don't use DomSanitizer how this works ?  I don't need safe url this time... hm

Comment: Try this https://plnkr.co/edit/CmolRdrrzY9LbOij39l7?p=preview I don't use DomSanitanizer because i'm working with dom directly

Comment: Thanks, I wonder what is the best your or juste this : I think my solution is faster no ? I just achieve this with ngIf https://plnkr.co/edit/0XhNUtP4ABnHwvoSE9Ia?p=preview but I need setTimeout, is there solution to delete this setTimeout when I remvoe it it wont' works ngIf don't hide/show directly maybe it's very speed

Comment: THANKS!!! this rooks !! it's really good and speed as that I don't need ngIf and setTimeout() many thanks !

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the best answer for my question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49355544/dynamic-youtube-iframe-in-angular-2-4

Comment: I am using embed, is there any way out ?

Answer (score 0):

first thanks you but I don't understand I have exactly the same and see the result

my embed is not display... i don't have css to hide it :

I think it is because I don't reinject embed tag? When I open sidenav my embed already exist I just change the src url and it doesn't realod content, is there solution ?

[image]

Comment: with firefox it works, how can I achieve with chrome, someone help me? even with ngIf it doesn't work

Answer (score -2):

But here you can see with **FIREFOX** it works fine :

[image: FIREFOX !!!]

Comment: this is not an answer.