# How to bind object into iframe src

Tags: javascript, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

I have added youtube iframe to my html file, but I want it to display the source based on the object from the backend instead of writing the url by hand like I have below. I have an object that stores the link from admin panel, it's called item.youtube. it works perfectly when I insert it inside `[href]` as you can see below, but certainly not with iframe. How can I bind it correctly?

Here is my html of an iframe inside modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span></button>
    <div class="modal-content">
          <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RnNwo8aLJJ4?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is my list of items with title, description etc. including title class that has above mentioned `[href]` that works perfectly:

```
<div class="paragraph-items" *ngFor="let section of page">

  <section class="news">


    <div class="news-items-wrapper">
      <div class="news-wrapper" *ngFor="let item of section.items">
        <div class="news-item-wrapper">
          <a class="thumb" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#"
             [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + item.thumbnail + ')'}">
          </a>
          <div class="info">
            <a class="title" [href]="item.youtube" target="_blank">{{ item.title }}</a>
            <div class="description" [innerHTML]="item.description"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem here is that iframe src's are protected in angular and marked as unsafe.
you can create a pipe and use the domsanitizer

like this

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```

then add your pipe to the app module

```
@NgModule({
   declarations : [
     ...
     SafePipe
   ],
})
```

in html you can use it like this

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" [src]="url | safe"></iframe>
```

you can read about it here
[how with angular2 rc.6 disable sanitize on embed html tag which display pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393431/how-with-angular2-rc-6-disable-sanitize-on-embed-html-tag-which-display-pdf/39394814#39394814)

Comment: First of all, thanks for your response. Actually, I didn't downvoted, I simply can't do it because I have less than 15 reputations xD. 
Your solution is correct. but I am having trouble inserting the pipe, it gives me an error: `zone.js:192 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'youtube' could not be found ("           <div class="modal-content">
                            <iframe width="560" height="315" [ERROR ->][src]="item.youtube | youtube" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyros"):`

Comment: you are using the pipe with the name youtube so check your Pipe and change @Pipe({ name: 'safe' }) into @Pipe({ name: 'youtube' })