# How can I pass HTML as string and bypass Security?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to use the ionic-alert-controller to show a message to the user. This message is rich-text and might contain links, which the alert actually allows and works like a charm for most of the links.

However (when the link is a deeplink to another app) Angular sometimes considers them unsafe, making the links unclickable. How can I prevent this behavior? The alert only accepts a string as message, no SafeHTML.

```js
this.a : string = getRichTextFromServer();

// EXAMPLE
// this.a = `<a href="www.google.de">works like a charm</a>
// Hello Hello <b>Example Text</b>
// <a href="sd-viewer://testlink">UNSAFE LINK</a>
// `;

// Some links are marked as unsafe
this.alertCtrl.create({
      message: this.a
    });
    
    
// Doesn't compile as message is only allowed to be a string
this.alertCtrl.create({
      message: this.domSan.bypassSecurityTrustHTML(this.a)
    });
    
// Gives error that function must be used with property binding
this.alertCtrl.create({
      message: this.domSan.bypassSecurityTrustHTML(this.a).toString()
    });
    
// Some links are marked as unsafe again
this.alertCtrl.create({
      this.ds.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML,
        this.ds.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(a)
      )
    });
```

What can I do here?

EDIT: The HTML (in my example stored in "a") is dynamically loaded from the backend and therefore not known at compiletime. Therefore, editing it to convert RichText to Angular Syntax at runtime seems quite hacky.

Answer (score 1):

hi i answered this yesterday here:
[How to bind object into iframe src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55143728/how-to-bind-object-into-iframe-src/55143881#55143881)

you can create a pipe and use the domsanitizer

like this

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```

then add your pipe to the app module

```
@NgModule({
   declarations : [
     ...
     SafePipe
   ],
})
```

in html you can use it like this (url is your unsafe url)

```
<a href="{{url | safe}}">UNSAFE LINK</a>
```

If it helps please mark my answer as correct, thanks!

Comment: So I would need to edit my HTML string by searching for any URLs and replace them with a pipe angular expression?

Comment: a pipe is the easiest way for that purpose, yes 
url = an unsafe url

please don't forget to mark the answer ;)

Comment: Hmmm, in that case its more a workaround than a solution... but maybe there is no solution, let's see if someone comes up with one :)

Comment: its no workaround, pipe's are the angular way you should go ;)

Comment: Okay, maybe here is a misunderstanding.
Your proposal would require me to directly alter my HTML (in my code example variable "a") which I don't know at compiletime as it comes from external ressources. I would need to parse the HTML and replace any found URL with a pipe programmaticly, which is quite hacky. It would be a conversion from simple RichText to Angular Syntax at runtime.
I see that I didn't made that point clear in my initial question and update it accordingly!

Comment: i guess you think far to complex in this case... url is a variable so somewhere in your controller you are receiving your data from your external ressources like in a get request. 
by using ng-for you should be able to loop through your data and replace the url with the pipe (in your view).

its a basic angular operation. maybe you should take a deeper look to the angular featureset.

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Checkout Hero Detail Component and Hero Search Component on this site

Comment: In how far is URL a variable? I don't have any URL in a variable, I have a richtext-html in a variable that might or might not contain URLs at some point.

Comment: sorry i didn't see that you get just a string, not an array..
well then you could detect urls  by using a regex pattern inside the string

this.a : string = getRichTextFromServer();
var regpat = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;

var resultarray = this.a.match(regpat);

the resultarray is an array holding all urls from richtext

maybe you should post how your view looks like and what you are going to do with your richtext

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190083/discussion-between-xzesstence-and-fortunenext).