# Angular 2.1.0 create child component on the fly, dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular

What i'm trying to do in `angular 2.1.0` is creating child components on the fly which should be injected into parent component. For example parent component is `lessonDetails` which contains shared stuff for all lessons such as buttons like `Go to previous lesson`, `Go to next lesson` and other stuff. Based on route params, lesson content which should be **child component** needs to be injected dynamically into **parent component**. HTML for child components (lesson content) is defined as plain string somewhere outside, it can be object like:

```
export const LESSONS = {
  "lesson-1": `<p> lesson 1 </p>`,
  "lesson-2": `<p> lesson 2 </p>`
}
```

Problem can be easily solved through `innerHtml` having something like following in **parent component** template.

```
<div [innerHTML]="lessonContent"></div>
```

Where on each change of route params, property `lessonContent` of parent component would change(content(new template) would be taken from `LESSON` object) causing parent component template to be updated. This works but angular will not process content injected through `innerHtml` so it is impossible to use `routerLink` and other stuff.

Before new angular release i solved this problem using solution from http://blog.lacolaco.net/post/dynamic-component-creation-in-angular-2/, where i have been using `ComponentMetadata` together with `ComponentResolver` to create child components on the fly, like:

```
const metadata = new ComponentMetadata({
  template: this.templateString,
});
```

Where `templateString` was passed to child component as `Input` property to child component. Both `MetaData` and `ComponentResolver` are deprecated/removed in `angular 2.1.0`.

So problem is not just about dynamic component creation, like described in few related SO questions, problem would be easier to solve if i would have defined component for each lesson-content. This would mean that i need to predeclare 100 different components for 100 different lessons. Deprecated Metadata was providing behaviour *that was like* updating template at runtime of single component(creating and destroying single component on route params change).

**Update 1:** As it seems in recent angular release, all components that needs to be created/injected dynamically needs to be predefined in `entryComponents` within `@NgModule`. So as it seems to me, related to question above, if i need to have 100 lessons(components that needs to be created dynamically on the fly) that means i need to predefine 100 components

**Update 2:** Based on Update 1, it can be done through `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` in following way:

```
// lessons.ts
@Component({ template: html string loaded from somewhere })
class LESSON_1 {}

@Component({ template: html string loaded from somewhere })
class LESSON_2 {}

// exported value to be used in entryComponents in @NgModule
export const LESSON_CONTENT_COMPONENTS = [ LESSON_1, LESSON_2 ]
```

Now in parent component on route params change

```
const key = // determine lesson name from route params

/**
 * class is just buzzword for function
 * find Component by name (LESSON_1 for example)
 * here name is property of function (class)
 */

const dynamicComponent = _.find(LESSON_CONTENT_COMPONENTS, { name: key });
const lessonContentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(dynamicComponent);
this.componentRef = this.lessonContent.createComponent(lessonContentFactory);
```

Parent template looks like:

```
<div *ngIf="something" #lessonContentContainer></div>
```

Where `lessonContentContainer` is decorated `@ViewChildren` property and `lessonContent` is decorated as `@ViewChild` and it is initialized in `ngAfterViewInit ()` as:

```
ngAfterViewInit () {
  this.lessonContentContainer.changes.subscribe((items) => {
    this.lessonContent = items.first;
    this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
      // logic that needs to show lessons
    })
  })
}
```

**Solution has one drawback** and that is, all components(LESSON_CONTENT_COMPONENTS) needs to be predefined.
 *Is there a way to use one single component and to change template of that component at runtime (on route params change)?*

Comment: See http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/structuredefinition-explicit-type-name. Adding HTML just adds HTML, if you want components dynamically you can use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()`. Otherwise components and directives are only created for selectors that are added statically to the template of a component.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thank you for reply, actually i'm using `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` please check Update 2 part in question

Comment: You can't modify the template of a component at runtime. There are ways to create new components at runtime. I don't know details about this but there are answers to similar questions on SO.

Comment: Similar issue is covered here [How can I use/create dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38888008/1679310)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the following `HtmlOutlet` directive:

```
import {
  Component,
  Directive,
  NgModule,
  Input,
  ViewContainerRef,
  Compiler,
  ComponentFactory,
  ModuleWithComponentFactories,
  ComponentRef,
  ReflectiveInjector
} from '@angular/core';

import { RouterModule }  from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

export function createComponentFactory(compiler: Compiler, metadata: Component): Promise<ComponentFactory<any>> {
    const cmpClass = class DynamicComponent {};
    const decoratedCmp = Component(metadata)(cmpClass);

    @NgModule({ imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule], declarations: [decoratedCmp] })
    class DynamicHtmlModule { }

    return compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(DynamicHtmlModule)
       .then((moduleWithComponentFactory: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any>) => {
        return moduleWithComponentFactory.componentFactories.find(x => x.componentType === decoratedCmp);
      });
}

@Directive({ selector: 'html-outlet' })
export class HtmlOutlet {
  @Input() html: string;
  cmpRef: ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private compiler: Compiler) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    const html = this.html;
    if (!html) return;

    if(this.cmpRef) {
      this.cmpRef.destroy();
    }

    const compMetadata = new Component({
        selector: 'dynamic-html',
        template: this.html,
    });

    createComponentFactory(this.compiler, compMetadata)
      .then(factory => {
        const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders([], this.vcRef.parentInjector);   
        this.cmpRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory, 0, injector, []);
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.cmpRef) {
      this.cmpRef.destroy();
    }    
  }
}
```

See also **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/mcvILwmOLvrS2PxIrXX8?p=preview)**

[Example with custom component](https://plnkr.co/edit/TAbupH4si62x10QZ7xuc?p=preview)

For AOT compilation see these threads

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15510
- http://blog.assaf.co/angular-2-harmony-aot-compilation-with-lazy-jit-2/

See also **github Webpack AOT example** https://github.com/alexzuza/angular2-build-examples/tree/master/ngc-webpack

Comment: thanks on nice answer. Just one more question, shouldnt we save reference to current `cmpRef` and destroy it manually before creating new dynamic component? Having something like in HtmlOutlet directive, `private cmpRef: ComponentRef<any>` then inside of `ngOnChanges` before creating new component `if (this.cmpRef) { this.cmpRef.destroy(); }`. Or it will be automatically destroyed?

Comment: Yes, of course. We have to do it manually. I'm not sure but seems `this.vcRef.clear` do the same thing. I updated my answer

Comment: Just one more question, a little bit unrelated to question. Trying to apply `safeHtml` pipe on html outlet directive as `<html-outlet [html]="htmlString | safeHtml></html-outlet>"` getting error `Cannot set property stack of [object Object] which has only a getter(…)`. safeHtml is very simple pipe having `transform` method implemented as `transform (html: string) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }`

Comment: Related answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037760/how-to-set-iframe-src-in-angular-2-without-causing-unsafe-value-exception/38037914#38037914

Comment: I've tried you're plnkr as a solution to my problem. This solution does not support custom components.  .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092639/how-to-render-a-dynamic-template-with-components-in-angular2#40092639, and i've created a new plnkr - https://plnkr.co/edit/UACDPBRWNmvjVVsr0dWC?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui, I want to access dom object of html-outlet, for that I have to create constructor inside dynamic component. But when I am creating **constructor(public eleRef: ElementRef) {}**, inside dynamic component, it's giving errot- **Can't resolve all parameters for DynamicComponent: (?)**

Comment: @rish Try to do the same at your root component. I guess you will get the same error

Comment: @yurzui, I tried inside root component, I am not getting error?

Comment: @yurzui I don't know it's possible or not but I want to get only DOM object from dynamic template I don't want to rendered the template. After getting DOM template I have to return it to metawidget API which take care of rendering part with some modification. So please suggest me if it's possible or not?

Comment: @rish Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40314136/dynamic-add-component-using-gridstack-and-angular2-jquery-parsehtml-does-not/40446974#40446974.Maybe it helps you.

Comment: nice solution, anyway I am having problem with using custom component solution. In my case angular always shout with 'some-componentt' is not a known element. I changed in your plunker test-component usage to home-component (<my-test></my-test> >>> <my-about></my-about>) and it also gets error. So only my-test can be used there but why ??

Comment: @user2771738 Can you show me this plunker that reproduces it?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/4AljRIDxU8rNzKlcOKFq?p=preview
in app.ts you can revert to my-test and it will be working. But only with this component

Comment: @user2771738 Why do you want to use the same component as in router configuration? https://plnkr.co/edit/klzTnlldGo57ETlqt0mm?p=preview You need to declare your desired component within SharedModule

Comment: Just in matter of tests. I am having almost same project structure but I cannot use nor the shared components nor the app components. I think thats the same problem, maybe some dependency cycle or something.

Comment: @user2771738 Can you share your project on github?

Comment: I will try to figure it out on my own a little bit more. I cannot publish whole project, so I need a little bit time to clean up it before publishing

Comment: Ok I found that i copied html outlet from example without imported shared module ... sry for problem. Works great!

Comment: @user2771738 Glad to hear :)

Comment: @yurzui  **[ts] Property 'find' does not exist on type 'ComponentFactory<any>[]'.**, this error I get. I am using angular 2.2

Comment: Using this solution, but since new angular-cli versions, it is throwing this error: No NgModule metadata found for 'DynamicHtmlModule'. Any suggestion?

Comment: Hello, I'm using Angular 4.1 and the signature of `createComponent` doesn't accept the factory anymore :
`this.vcRef.createComponent(factory, 0, injector, []);` throws "Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type `ComponentFactory<{}>` for the first parameter

Comment: @AlexandreCouret Are you sure? https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.1.1/packages/core/src/linker/view_container_ref.ts#L85-L86 How do you get componentFactory? Can you create a plunker?

Comment: @yurzui In my string template i'm using `ngFor.` But the dynamic module is not containing Common module How can I import the common  module into the dynamic module ?

Comment: @yurzui How can we use angular's interpolation inside the html passed to the dynamic component? Like `'<div> Mix at {{speed}} rpm</div>'`

Comment: @yurzui If I use expression inside the braces like the one in your plunker example it will work. But when I give variable it's not working.

Comment: @SruthiVarghese Can you reproduce it?

Comment: @yurzui For example if I use a variable instead of the expression  {{5 + 6}} in your code nothing is showing the UI. It's coming as blank

Comment: @yurzui I copy paste your plunkr code and it works for me too. May be there was some mistake where I was initializing the variable. Thanks man .