# Dynamic Template Loading in Angular2

Tags: angular

I just started learning angular2 and I am trying to do sample program on dynamic template loading. I am following this [link](http://blog.lacolaco.net/post/dynamic-component-creation-in-angular-2/)

But because **ComponentResolver** is deprecated, so I am not able to execute this code. Can any one help me, how I can do the same on stable version of Angular2.

Comment: You can find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060498/angular-2-1-0-create-child-component-on-the-fly-dynamically

Comment: @yurzui, thank you so much

Comment: Similar issue is covered here [How can I use/create dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38888008/1679310)