# angular lazy loading of component without router or import or loadChildren

Tags: angular

Is there a way in angular to lazy load component directly from the tag in html like `<my-component></my-component>`?

during component template parsing, angular should load the entire component into the browser when it finds any new tag which is not available in html or not already loaded.

I know we can load a module using `loadChildren` which is only specific to routing and also need to load the module and its component. I am searching only for component and directly the component not the module.

I dont want to use router or dont want to import the component ot module in my application. I want when angular2 will find a tag which is not in html5 it will search in a spcictfic folder and load the js and html file and inject that component in the specific tag

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular/38888009#38888009

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293240/how-to-manually-lazy-load-a-module

Comment: @yurzui The duplicate marked link is about lazy loading of module not component. I have asked how to lazy load the component without thinking about the module or anything else.

Comment: Angular doesn't support lazy loading component without module. In any case you have to create module even that will consist of only one component

Comment: @yurzui so the question is not duplicate right?

Comment: looks like these are 2 different question not duplicate

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have to use **dynamic component loading** with component builder, which has limitation with AOT, Dynamic component will not work with AOT.

Dynamic component loading will find your tag and load appropriate component in DOM

Comment: Dynamic component can work with AOT

Comment: Can I have article Or link where I can look. I really required to implement in my project

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060498/angular-2-1-0-create-child-component-on-the-fly-dynamically/40080290#40080290 `For AOT compilation see these threads`

Comment: @yurzui: Thanks for link, I will check and let you know if any help is required.

Comment: @yurzui : the link you have given is not complete dynamic component loading, it is like dynamic html loading. I required run time component load in DOM by given "Selector".

Comment: Can you create example of what you are looking for? `System.import` and then `compile.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(loadedModule)`?

Comment: then you can use `componentFactory.create(..., givenSelector)`

Comment: find one of my question on it here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/42551380/6606630

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/shlomiassaf/lazy-jit? Main bundle will work with AOT while your factory for creating dynamic components will be loaded by demand and it won't use AOT compilation. If you create dynamically module AOT compile can't create factory for it so using AOT for this part makes no sense

Comment: In above example you runtime add RunTimeCompiledComponent in RuntimeComponentModule with entry point define. What if i have multiple component and among that i have to add any one in "RuntimeComponentModule"? not the default one (RunTimeCompiledComponent). In my page no any predefined that this component will load dynamic, it's by configuration so any comonent can load dynamically