# Angular2 : Dynamic component creation : AOT Compilation

Tags: angular, angular2-aot, ng-modules

Below is my **initial code to create dynamic module**:

```
protected createComponentModule(componentType: any) {

    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            ComponentModule 
        ],
        declarations: [
            componentType
        ],
    })
    class RuntimeComponentModule {
    }
    return RuntimeComponentModule;

}
```

While I am going to implement **AOT** on below code it throw me error:

> No NgModule metadata found for 'RuntimeComponentModule'

I found solution of it some Articals by change below code and my error gone away:

```
default class RuntimeComponentModule 
{
}
```

But new error is raised it say:

> Modifiers cannot appear here

It not allowed me to decorate @NgModule within method.

Comment: You can refer this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular

Comment: @Karan: no luck, I have already tried it

Comment: @Karan Patel , Already referred this link. but with AOT it's not working.

Comment: check the readme here: [https://github.com/laco0416/ng-dynamic](https://github.com/laco0416/ng-dynamic)

Answer (score 1):

Using dynamic component or module creation is currently not officially supported to be used together with AoT

See the discussion at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11780 for possible workarounds.

Comment: I also think so, I have already tried so many ways but no luck