# Trouble shoot "Runtime compiler is not loaded"

Tags: angular

I am getting the following runtime error after building my Angular2 app with the `--prod` flag:

> Runtime compiler is not loaded

I understand that the production builds use AoT and that runtime compiling isn't supported in this scenario.
My problem is: I am not aware of anything I am doing that would need the runtime compiler. It might even be an external component I am using.

How do I find out what component is causing this error?

Comment: What 3rd-party packages are you using?

Comment: Quite a few. I found out that the problem was the usage of DynamicComponent by angular2-busy. However, I found this out only because that component stopped working. Isn't there a more deterministic approach?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "deterministic approach". If you create components at runtime you currently can't use AoT. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/42619501/217408

Comment: With deterministic approach I mean: How do I find out in a deterministic way WHICH component is creating components at runtime?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I'd suggest you create a bug report for a better error message.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14981

Comment: I also experienced this same issue and it was also caused by angular2-busy.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the similar issue with AoT compilation when I was trying to use lazy module loading using module type instead of the path.

Correct loading:

```
{ path: 'lazy', loadChildren: 'lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' }
```

Way, I've done it (crashes AoT):

```
export function loadLazyModule() {
  return LazyModule;
}
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'lazy', loadChildren: loadLazyModule, },
];
```

Indeed the error message is not helpful at all, however, the stack trace is:

```
at Compiler.compileModuleAsync (core.js:3664)
at MergeMapSubscriber.eval [as project] (router.js:4467)
```

I've just made a breakpoint at `compileModuleAsync` function and at the stop I saw the module which was causing the error.