# Why are my routes not loading the right child?

Tags: angular, typescript, module, routes

I'm currently studying Angular (CLI v7.1.0) and I'm a little bit confused with routing/modules. I'm building a test application where I want public and admin components in different modules. This is what my application looks like:

[image]

(All URLs are just for explanatory purposes)

The public module should be visible to anyone who accesses http://mywebsite.com, the admin module should be accessed through http://mywebsite.com/admin. Each module has a component called **WrapperComponent** (which I need to wrap shared components like headers, navbars, etc...) and it'll navigate through all pages in the admin module, making `router-outlet` needed in it's HTML file.

### app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AdminModule } from './modules/admin/admin.module';
import { PublicModule } from './modules/public/public.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AdminModule,
    PublicModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### app-routing.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'public',
    loadChildren: './modules/public/public.module#PublicModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: './modules/admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

### public.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { PublicRoutingModule } from './public-routing.module';
import { WrapperComponent } from './wrapper/wrapper.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent, WrapperComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, PublicRoutingModule]
})
export class PublicModule { }
```

### public-routing.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { WrapperComponent } from './wrapper/wrapper.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: WrapperComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PublicRoutingModule { }
```

> **admin.module.ts** and **admin-routing.module.ts** look pretty much the same as the public module. I won't add it here to not extend the question but it's available at [GitHub](https://github.com/thsilvab/udemy-angular/tree/master/bootstrapping/src/app/modules/admin).

### The problem

I've tried to make `path: '', redirectTo: '/public'` in the **app-routing.module.ts** but it doesn't redirect to the public module. When I removed this route from my array both wrappers (public and admin) loaded. I need to do as I explained above but I'm a little bit lost. I've been reading some other questions here and the [Angular docs for lazy loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) + [Angular docs for Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router).

Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the problem is that you need to use `lazy loading` (that's the easier way, but if you dont want to use `lazy loading` its also [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45447069/routing-to-sub-routing-module-without-lazy-loading)) - and that's this `loadChildren` property in the `routing module`.

So the `app-routing.module.ts` should look like this (check the correct paths).

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'public',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'public',
    loadChildren: './modules/public/public.module#PublicModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: './modules/admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And also remove the `PublicModule` and `AdminModule` from the `imports` in the `app.module.ts`

[There is simple understandable example of lazy loading modules.](https://stackblitz.com/angular/rxdonyxndrk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts)

Comment: I saw the example you provided, I think it's pretty much what I'm doing, except for the wrapper component (I still doubt I'll keep it). I've posted the wrong code for **app-routing.module.ts**. I've corrected it, my apologies.

Comment: check my edited answer. try place the path: ' ' route above the other routes in the app module

Comment: It worked when I removed `PublicModule` and `AdminModule` from `app.module.ts`, why wasn't it working with these imports?

Comment: The problem is that you were lazy-loading the modules while they have been already imported at the compilation (or something like that, I just think this is the problem). Anyway, happy that is it working now :)