# AngularCli & AOT: ERROR Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I'm trying to build my Angular4 application with Ahead of Time. 
The build process runs fine and without errors, but when I run the application I receive this error in console:

```
ERROR Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded
    at J (vendor.ac8dafb82366354245dd.bundle.js:1)
    at t.compileModuleSync (vendor.ac8dafb82366354245dd.bundle.js:1)
    at t.QFu1.t.createDynamicTemplate (vendor.ac8dafb82366354245dd.bundle.js:1)
    at t.QFu1.t.ngDoCheck (vendor.ac8dafb82366354245dd.bundle.js:1)
    at xn (vendor.ac8dafb82366354245dd.bundle.js:1)
    at pr (vendor.ac8dafb82366354245dd.bundle.js:1)
    at cr (vendor.ac8dafb82366354245dd.bundle.js:1)
    at Yr (vendor.ac8dafb82366354245dd.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.updateDirectives (vendor.ac8dafb82366354245dd.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.updateDirectives (vendor.ac8dafb82366354245dd.bundle.js:1)
b @ vendor.ac8dafb82366354245dd.bundle.js:1
vendor.ac8dafb….bundle.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'ws://null/algorilla/ws/websocket/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
r @ vendor.ac8dafb….bundle.js:1
```

The application is navigable, but nothing works as it should!
What I'm doing wrong? Why the compiled code references to a Runtime compiler?

I don't use any angular/compile components or service.

In my components I reference the service mock in this way:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-authorization',
  templateUrl: './authorization.component.html',
  providers: [
    { provide: SecurityService, useClass: (environment.mock ? SecurityServiceMock : SecurityService) }
  ]
})
```

If the var "environment.mock" is true, I use SecurityServiceMock, otherwise the real SecurityService.

Could this be the problem?

This is tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noStrictGenericChecks": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "0.9.6",
  "description": "xxx",
  "author": "",
  "url": "xxx",
  "copyright": "xxx",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/common": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/upgrade": "4.4.3",
    "@stomp/ng2-stompjs": "^0.4.2",
    "@types/highcharts": "^4.2.57",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.43",
    "@types/sockjs-client": "^1.0.32",
    "angular2-busy": "^2.0.4",
    "angular2-csv": "^0.2.5",
    "angular2-notifications": "^0.7.7",
    "angular2-prettyjson": "2.0.5",
    "angular2-websocket-service": "^0.5.3",
    "angular2gridster": "^0.6.7",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "highcharts": "^4.2.7",
    "js-beautify": "1.7.3",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "ng2-daterangepicker": "^2.0.7",
    "ng2-highcharts": "^1.0.0",
    "ng2-stomp-service": "^1.2.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.0-beta.6",
    "ngx-contextmenu": "^1.3.5",
    "ngx-cookie": "^1.0.0",
    "ngx-loading": "^1.0.5",
    "queueing-subject": "^0.1.1",
    "roboto-fontface": "^0.8.0",
    "roboto-mono-webfont": "^2.0.986",
    "rxjs": "5.4.1",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.1.4",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
    "t-json-viewer": "^1.2.0",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "typescript": "^2.4.0",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "vkbeautify": "0.99.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.47",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.22",
    "codelyzer": "3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.0",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.0.4",
    "tslint": "5.3.2",
    "typescript": "2.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11780?

Comment: Yes, but I dont have any COMPILER_PROVIDERS declared in my modules

Comment: Please add your package.json. Which libraries are you using?

Comment: A lot. Updated the post

Comment: Find `createDynamicTemplate` method in your code. It can be inside node_modules

Comment: Bingo! I found in one external module! I'll try to disable this module. I let you know, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `compileModuleSync` from the [**Compiler**](https://angular.io/api/core/Compiler) service, which is called by the `createDynamicTemplate` method. The angular compiler cli is analyzing your code and is creating [**metadata**](https://angular.io/guide/metadata) from your templates and classes (ngFactory files) and removes the compiler module entirely from your application when using AOT.

Don't use any services or methods from the `angular/compiler` package if you want to use AOT.

Could you add the `package.json` file to your answer, there might be a 3rd party library which isn't AOT ready.

---

*Sitenote:*
The way you're mocking your services looks a little bit weird, you could just provide the service and then override it if `environment.mock` ist true. For example:

```
let myProviders = [
  SecurityService
];

if(environment.mock) {
  myProviders.push(
    { provide: SecurityService, useClass: SecurityServiceMock }
  )
}

// ...

providers: [
  ...myProviders
]
```

But that's not the cause of the `Runtime compiler is not loaded` error.

Update:

I found out that the error is caused by the [angular2-busy](https://github.com/devyumao/angular2-busy) package you're using.

Comment: In my components I mock the services in this way:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-authorization',
  templateUrl: './authorization.component.html',
  providers: [
    { provide: SecurityService, useClass: (environment.mock ? SecurityServiceMock : SecurityService) },
    { provide: DashboardManagerService, useClass: (environment.mock ? DashboardManagerServiceMock : DashboardManagerService) }
  ]
})

It could be the problem?

Comment: Add the relevant code to your answer and we could help you to make it AOT ready. Somewhere in your code  you're using the `compileModuleSync ` method or some method which calls it.

Comment: Could you also add the `package.json` file?

Answer (score 0):

this is about WebSocket url check it see it in your code.

WebSocket connection to 'ws://**null**/algorilla/ws/websocket/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

you have a variable for the path and it is set to null ;)

Comment: That's not the problem. The message is caused by the `runtime compiler is not loaded` error caused by using the compiler service withing an AOT compiled application.

Comment: No, it was another problem, nothing to do with "Runtime compiler is not loaded" error

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @cyrix in comments I've searched for compileModuleSync in nodeModules and I find an external component that was using the angular compiler.

The external module was angular2-busy.

Removing it fixed the problem!

Comment: Yeah that's what i found out too, just added it to my answer.