# Angular dynamic template rendering like ui grid cell template (template declared in colDefs of parent)

Tags: angular, typescript, ui-grid, ng-template, dynamicgridview

Angular (7) dynamic template (ng-template) rendering like ui grid cell template (template declared in colDefs of parent); I tried in so many ways since more than 30 days, watched ng-template rendering videos, articles, but could'not find any solution, kindly help me here.

Thanks in advance :)

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
name = 'Angular';
gridOptions:any;

constructor(private http: HttpClient){}


ngOnInit(){

  this.gridOptions = {
    colDefs:[
     {name:'id', displayName:'ID',width:80},
     {name:'name', displayName:'Name'},
     {name:'username', displayName:'Username', cellTemplate:'Static text from template'},
     {name:'email', displayName:'Email', cellTemplate:'{{row[col.name]}}'},  // i tried like this
     {name:'phone', displayName:'phone', cellTemplate:"<strong style='color:blue'> + row[col.name] + </strong>"}, // I need to achive this kind of template like ui grid for angularjs
     {name:'website', displayName:'website', cellTemplate:'row[col.name]'}, // i tried like this also
    ]
   }

   this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").subscribe((res) =>{
    this.gridOptions.data = res;
  });

 }

}
```

**data-table.component.ts**

```
export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() gridOptions: any = [];
  constructor() { } 
 
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**data-table.component.html**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let col of gridOptions.colDefs">{{col.name}}</th>
    </tr>

    <tr *ngFor="let row of gridOptions.data ;let i = index">
        <td *ngFor="let col of gridOptions.colDefs">
            <ng-container *ngIf="!col.cellTemplate else myTemplate" [ngTemplateOutlet]="myTemplate">
                {{row[col.name]}}
            </ng-container>
            <ng-template #myTemplate row="row" col="col">
                {{col.cellTemplate}}
            </ng-template>

            <!-- <ng-template #myTemplate row="row" col="col" innerHTML="col.cellTemplate}"></ng-template> -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-data-table [gridOptions]="gridOptions"></app-data-table>
```

[image: a busy cat]

**[StackBlitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-template-rendering-like-ui-grid-cell-template)**

Comment: why didn't you add the cellTemplate to the template and add condition, instead of defining them in the ts file?

Comment: It should work for any time of cellTemplate for any kind of json like ui grid, I have to keep adding conditions for diff json service, here the **data-table** component should be common

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-template-rendering-like-ui-grid-cell-tem) demo that I created for you. It's leverage the render function `cellFn` in which you can customize template as you please. Also notice the usage of `safeHtml` pipe to render html inside template.

**EDIT**: As the OP stated in comments, he also wants to use Angular directives etc. in template. So here is the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-template-rendering-compile-directive) demo for this purpose.

Comment: wooww... thanks lot @**Bardr**, excellent answer, you have saved me time n mind from this big problem in angular project. just thanks is not enough to you.. god bless you..

Comment: @RajGopal No problem. I'm glad I helped.

Comment: Hi @Bardr, I need one more help from you, ngClass is not working, could you pls check ---------            `{ name: 'name', displayName: 'Name', cellFn: rowData => '<span [ngClass]="{'red':${rowData.name} == 'Ervin Howell'}">${rowData.name}<span>'  }`

Comment: I am not able to use any angular attributes in this case

Comment: @RajGopal Yes, and this is obvious. They will be just rendered as a plain HTML. No magic here. Do you only need `[ngClass]` or more eloquent directives? `[ngClass]` equivalent can be simply made inside `cellFn` function.

Comment: I need all ng directives, do we have any other method to achieve this kind of template definitions. Especially i need u use ngif, ngclass and ngmodel..

Comment: Thanks @Bardr, works perfectly as i expected, thank you so much for your help

Comment: Hi @Bardr, this is not working in production, I am facing issue like "**Runtime compiler is not loaded**" after build --prod, Do you have any idea about this.

Comment: @RajGopal Because you are compiling components dynamically, you need compiler. But in AOT (which is enabled by default by `--prod` flag), compiler is not included. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42706113/angular-cli-build-prod-runtime-compiler-is-not-loaded/42843683

Answer (score 1):

AS far as I know DataTables doesn't support any Angular magic.
I handled similar problems with the render-functions which DataTables offers you: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render#function

For example you would need to change the row:

```
{name:'email', displayName:'Email', cellTemplate:'{{row[col.name]}}'},
```

to:

```
{name:'email', displayName:'Email', render:(data, type, row, meta) => 'contact ' + row.name + ' via E-Mail'},
```

I hope this helps.