# Ionic 4 Production Build - Runtime compiler is not loaded Error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using the command `ionic build --prod` to build my PWA for production hosting (using Firebase). When running the production build I get the following error in the browser console:

> ERROR Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42706113/angular-cli-build-prod-runtime-compiler-is-not-loaded) suggests that AoT my be the issue. I tried running `ionic build --prod --aot=false` but the problem persists. I am not sure that it is a valid parameter when using ionic and I'd rather fix the issue than finding a workaround anyway.

Besides the error, the site also does not load correctly. It just sits at a plain white screen. What is causing this error?

package.json

```
{
  "name": "MYSITE",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.803.6",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",
    "angularfire2": "^5.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "dom-to-image": "^2.6.0",
    "firebase": "^6.6.1",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.4",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.5.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": []
  }
}
```

Comment: does ionic build works perfectly...?

Comment: Yes, the dev build works perfectly and runs fine.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57410728/5909026

Answer (score 0):

In `tsconfig.json` you will find `angularCompilerOptions`. Please add `enableIvy: true` like this:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true,
}
```

This worked for me with Ionic `4.11.7` and Angular `8.2.14`