# Dynamic compilation of an element in angular

Tags: angular

The question is same as [Equivalent of $compile in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2)

But I have an element

```
<div>Hello {{name}}!</div>
```

I have defined `name` in the class as

```
this.name = "<b>Mr_Perfect {{job}}</b>";
this.job  = "UI Developer";
```

Now, I need to compile the `div` dynamically. I just checked the above link and few answers are deprecated and the accepted answer in the question is good but need to write a lot of code just to compile a small element.

Are there any better methods in the recent releases of angular?

Comment: You have to use compiler. That accepted answer does it. Here the same way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060498/angular-2-1-0-create-child-component-on-the-fly-dynamically

Comment: I didn't understand that code cleary. Can you explain it as a answer?

Comment: If you don't use any angular binding you should use `innerHTML/outerHTML`

Comment: you should read [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
<div>Hello <span [innerHTML]=name></span>!</div>
```

Comment: The main motto of the question is to know about dynamic compilation but not getting output. Check updated question