# Angular 2 iFrame giving errors even after sanitization

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

I am trying to include an iFrame in my Angular 2 app but I keep getting the following error,

> unsafe value used in a resource URL context

I am trying to generate a dynamic URL to send as a param into the iFrame.

```
<iframe [src]="url" width="560" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>

    ngOnInit(): void {

    this.myData = this.store.select<myState>('myData').subscribe(state => {
      this.myData = state.myData;
      this.loading = state.loading;

      if (this.myData) {
        this.url = `www.google.com`;
      }

      console.log(this.url);
    });
  }
```

I have tried to implement both these solutions but still getting the same error

[How to set iframe src in Angular 2 without causing `unsafe value` exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037760/how-to-set-iframe-src-in-angular-2-without-causing-unsafe-value-exception)

and

https://plnkr.co/edit/Uifk3dxf7vwKJsUFb0d9?p=preview . which I got from an other stack overflow answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I did a wrong implementation so one answer from an other thread was failing, but someone pointed out my mistake and now the implementation works. Here is the link that worked for me

[How to set iframe src in Angular 2 without causing `unsafe value` exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037760/how-to-set-iframe-src-in-angular-2-without-causing-unsafe-value-exception)