# Iframes in Angular2

Tags: angular

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
             <iframe src="http://hssa:1021/Home?testRequestId=+[testRequestId]+" allowfullscreen></iframe>`,
})
export class AppComponent  {
    name = 'Angular';
    testRequestId = '3224'; 
}
```

I have my `.ts` file as mentioned above. How do I pass `testRequestId` to html?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set iframe src in Angular 2 without causing \`unsafe value\` exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037760/how-to-set-iframe-src-in-angular-2-without-causing-unsafe-value-exception)

Answer (score 11):

try this:

[Online demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/PJQx02?p=preview)

**Safe Pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(url: string) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```

**AppComponent**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <iframe [src]="'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + testRequestId | safe" width="560" height="315" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  testRequestId: string = 'uelHwf8o7_U';

}
```

because Angular not trust any source, it'll sanitize the content, then we need bypass it.

Learn more about this topic: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html

[Template syntax](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding)

Comment: If I change as mentioned, it gives the URL on debugging like this hssa:1021/Home?testRequestId=, which wont work. The testRequestId is getting passed as empty here.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error TS7006 Parameter 'url' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: huh, this is not Angular bug, just VS build tool. `testRequestId: string = 'uelHwf8o7_U';`

Comment: i just add Type for both code above, please config your IDE to ignore this issue `Parameter 'xxx' implicitly has an 'any' type`

Comment: Its still the same even after adding the line testRequestId: string = 'uelHwf8o7_U';

Comment: `transform(url: string)` this line too

Answer (score 0):

Just change `+[testRequestId]+` to `{{testRequestId}}`.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
<iframe src="http://hssa:1021/Home?testRequestId={{testRequestId}}"    allowfullscreen></iframe>`,
})
export class AppComponent  {
    name = 'Angular';
    testRequestId = '3224';
}
```

Comment: If I change as mentioned, it gives the URL on debugging like this http://hssa:1021/Home?testRequestId={{testRequestId}}, which wont work.

Comment: You can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037760/how-to-set-iframe-src-in-angular-2-without-causing-unsafe-value-exception