# ngFor youtube links with Domsanitizer in Angular2

Tags: angular, youtube, sanitize, angular-dom-sanitizer

I have youtube links in my mock memory database and I want to *ngFor these videos from youtube.

```
   let videos: any[] =[
            {videoURL: "ZOd5LI4-PcM"},
            {videoURL: "d6xQTf8M51A"},
            {videoURL :"BIfvIdEJb0U"}

        ];
```

like this.

I used service to connect my component with the server and now in the html, I have
let v of videos. And within the iframe tages.. I did

```
<iframe src=v.videoURL></iframe>
```

But since it's external source, they are telling me to use Domsanitzer but I am stuck at this part.

I don't know how to sanitize links that are supposed to be looping.

```
constructor( private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('')
```

<- I don't know what to add here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create pipe like:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```

And use it the following way:

```
<div *ngFor="let video of videos">
  <iframe [src]="('https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + video.videoURL) | safe"></iframe>
</div>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/nvEVUMiNzHeIQbmnUpZC?p=preview)**

See also

- [How to set iframe src in Angular 2 without causing `unsafe value` exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037760/how-to-set-iframe-src-in-angular-2-without-causing-unsafe-value-exception)