# How to load angular2 application or component via http

Tags: angular, angular2-components

Is it possible to load an Angular2 application or component via http? What I'm looking for is something like that:

Template:

`<app-local></app-local>
 <app-http></app-http>`

AppComponent of app-local:

`[...]
loadComponent("http://someurl/", "http-app");
[...]`

where app-http is an app or component from another url. After calling "loadComponent" the placeholder "http-app" should be replaced by the application. I don't know how to describe it better, but I hope someone understands what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use iFrame for this task.

Comment: yes I know, but I hoped that there would be a good angular2 solution...

Comment: It could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037760/how-to-set-iframe-src-in-angular-2-without-causing-unsafe-value-exception

Answer (score 4):

In AngularJS 2 you can Eagerly or Lazy Load Modules, not Components, perhaps you already know this, Lazy loading the Module will satisfy your goal. The module could just contain one Component.

However you may find you have to Lazy Load the Module from the same URL as the AngularJS 2 app was requested from.

Here is more on Lazy Loading Modules in AngularJS 2: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html

Comment: thank you, but in this solution I have to load the module from a local path. Perhaps using iframes could be the only solution for this task...

Comment: @geronimo678 You can Lazy Load from a local url, again if you are trying to load Module parts from different urls I am not sure Angular 2 supports that. Either way, I would bet you have not solved your problem and you are making things too complex because you desire to Lazy load app pieces from different URLs in the first place

Comment: Yes, you're right my problem is actually not solved. I'm thinking about the possibility of lazy load components from a local url instead of a remote url. If this is possible in my situation that would be more secure than load from a remote url.