# Possibility of using Angular 2 component in another non angular application as of iframe

Tags: angular

I need to use one component of an angular application in another non angular html. Is it possible to use one component alone in another application.?.. I need to get data in something like iframe

Comment: did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037760/how-to-set-iframe-src-in-angular-2-without-causing-unsafe-value-exception

Comment: My use case is different. I have one html page, to that page i need to call one angular 2 component from several components.. Is it possible to show only one component..??

Comment: Yes but you'll have to create a separate route that reveals only that component of yours