# How do I debug Angular 2 innerHTML in chrome Elements Tab?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, debugging, innerhtml

The problem I am having is the elements inside `innerHTML` when viewed in chrome's Debug -> Elements tab constantly collapse and refresh..  Assumedly due to it being bound dynamically.  Perhaps there is some way to stop,  or pause the update / change detection?

I am using the following code..  Just need a fix for debugging purposes as I need to look at Element's  Styles in Chrome Debug Console.

```
<mat-card-content>
   <div [innerHTML]="getUnSanitizedLessonHTML()" class="mat-typography"></div>
</mat-card-content>
```

And

```
  public getUnSanitizedLessonHTML() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.lesson.HTML);
  }
```

I have searched for a way to stop or pause JS in Chrome..  With no luck.
And I took a stab at inserting a 10 sec pause into 'getUnSanitizedLessonHTML()' with no success.

Thanks..

Comment: Use pure pipe for it like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037760/how-to-set-iframe-src-in-angular-2-without-causing-unsafe-value-exception/38037914#38037914 your `getUnSanitizedLessonHTML` method will be executed whenever new change detection cycle happens

Comment: Add a break-point on that line ?

Comment: Thanks to both of  you for super fast response..  [@yurzui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5485167/yurzui), Pure pipe looks super promising.   [@Ante Jablan Adamović](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2902161/ante-jablan-adamovi%c4%87)  - I am embarrased to say I have never used breakpoints in Angular / webDev.  A good prompt to learn now..    Been unable to get augury to work in past.. And my Souces tab never looks like what you see in [debugging-angular-2-applications](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/debugging-angular-2-applications)

Comment: And in 2 min of research I learned it..  Add debugger; to source..  :)