# Angular Property Binding or Interpolation

Tags: javascript, angular

I am having trouble understanding property binding with interpolation.

The below code is the correct way to assign src for an iframe.

```
<iframe [src]='sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(video.url)' frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But I would like to concatenate url straight ahead with id. I manage to write the code below but I am sure it is wrong.

```
<iframe [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("' + https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + '"video.id)" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

So can any one guide on how to concatenate strings during binding and interpolation? Also some explanation or link to any guide will be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set iframe src in Angular 2 without causing \`unsafe value\` exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037760/how-to-set-iframe-src-in-angular-2-without-causing-unsafe-value-exception)

Comment: @rrd thanks for the URL. That helps. but my question here is about how to use a string and a variable while using property binding.

Comment: you should format your url code such a way that you should not add new text othewise this is know behaviour of

Comment: @Dipakchavda So your suggestion is to feed the entire url to the sanitize function instead of creating the URL inside it?

Comment: @KiranDash Please review my answer it will probably helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**

I believe you have just added more quotation marks than necessary. I think that this should work better:

```
<iframe [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + video.id)"></iframe>
```

---

**Second**

I would not recommend sanitizing the input directly inline. I suggest you use component inner logic to sanitize your insecure data. Build the url completaly within some inner function of your component, the odds well might be you would not need the sanitizer at all then.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I understand now. But I am still facing some issue: the iframe keeps reloading when I use interpolation but it just works fine without it. I will keep digging to find an alternate solution.

Comment: @KiranDash - I guess that depends on the life cycle of the component ... if you do not change the value dynamically, but you refresh the component somehow, the binding process would be triggered with every refresh ... hence it is better to not bind it with interpolation like [attr]=value but rather just assing it attr="value" ... the [] interpolation binding is ideal for dynamically changed values see the docs at https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Comment: thanks for nice explanation. So I there a way to call the sanitizer function and use the interpolation inline without using databinding? Or do I need to just create the URL outside and then use it in src?

Comment: @KiranDash - It is much more convenient to declare some variable within you component.ts  file and assing the url value to it, then you use that variable as a reference within your template.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I ended up doing that. Have a good one. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please review following working code and review plunkr as well.

https://plnkr.co/edit/tYq22VjwB10WmytQO9Pb?p=preview

> index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="plunker">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <p>{{movie.src}}</p>
            <iframe ng-src="{{trustSrc(movie.src)}}"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

> app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
  }

  $scope.movie = {src:"https://www.youtube.com/embed/Lx7ycjC8qjE", title:"Egghead.io AngularJS Binding"};
});
```