# How do I pass on data to a html tag

Tags: typescript, angular5

I am very new to typescript. I want to create an iframe in my html file (or if possible, create it whole in my typescript file) and at the right moment pass on the url for that iframe via my typescript file. How would I go about doing this?
EDIT: I am trying to make a silent iframe to handle my token refreshing.

Comment: didn't this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38037914/8990367)  help?

Comment: Hello. When I tried doing that, I got this error: The pipe 'safe' could not be found