# *ngFor data not displaying

Tags: arrays, angular, display, ngfor

I'm trying to display on a table some tracks with spotify api, and it's not displaying anything. Here's the code

This is the tracksArray from the console.

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {uri: ""}
1: {uri: "spotify:track:4JhloJcv1weqqs8RfBLWk0"}
2: {uri: "spotify:track:7rHJr8x10nTZYR4j2VYlXu"}
3: {uri: "spotify:track:60SdxE8apGAxMiRrpbmLY0"}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Here's the html

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-favtracks',
    template: `
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="styled-tableheader">Vista Previa</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let track of tracksArray">
            <td>
            <iframe
              [src]="track.uri | domsanitizer"
              width="320"
              height="90"
              frameborder="0"
              allowtransparency="true"
              allow="encrypted-media"
            ></iframe> 
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./favtracks.component.scss'],
    providers: [SpotifyService]
})
```

Comment: are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: This Question is already fixed by other users . Please Follow the reference link mentioned below . [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037760/how-to-set-iframe-src-in-angular-2-without-causing-unsafe-value-exception) Kindly Mention the DomSanitizer pipe , code also.

Comment: Hey Jason, no, I'm not getting any errors on the console

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? I haven't seen `moduleId: module.id` done since version 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a proper DomSanitizer pipe you should get the elements properly, however I believe you are trying to display the uri by itself. I don't know if there's a way for that to work on its own, but if you put `https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=` in front of each of your `uri`, it should work. You could either do that in your template like so:

#### Template

```
<iframe
          [src]="'https://embed.spotify.com/?uri='+track.uri | SafePipe"
          width="320"
          height="90"
          frameborder="0"
          allowtransparency="true"
          allow="encrypted-media"
        ></iframe>
```

*(Or save it as variable in your .ts then use that instead of writing the whole string in the template)*

---

Or you can modify your array in your .ts, if you wanna keep the `uri` as they are for other things just add a property to your array:

#### Component

```
 ngOnInit() {
      this.tracksArray.forEach(e => {
        e["embeddedUri"] = "https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=" + e.uri;
      });
    }
```

#### Template

```
<iframe
          [src]="track.embeddedUri | SafePipe"
          width="320"
          height="90"
          frameborder="0"
          allowtransparency="true"
          allow="encrypted-media"
        ></iframe>
```