# how to open a link and contain it within a div

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to click on a link and open it inside a div on my page.

Here's the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kybqmc)!

```
<div class="container">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <a href="www.company.com/projects">projects</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="www.company.com/tasks">tasks</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="www.company.com/notifications">notifications</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="www.company.com/overview">overview</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

When a link is clicked, the page should open within the container div, without the address bar.

**UPDATE** - If these links were internal to the company, would an I frame still be the right way to go?

Comment: You are describing an [iFrame](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp)

Comment: One last question - If these links were internal to the company, would an I frame still be the right way to go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an iframe to your  container.
By clicking the link, you have to update the iframe.src attribut to fill your clicked link

I have update the example for you [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x2mikc):

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  link;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  openLink(url) {
    this.link = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
      url
    )
  }
}
```

Html :

```html
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>

<p>When a link is clicked, for example "Google", the page<br>
  should open inside the orange div (without the address bar).</p>

<div class="container">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <div (click)="openLink('www.google.com')">Google</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div (click)="openLink('www.amazon.com')">Amazon</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div (click)="openLink('www.linkedin.com')">Linkedin</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div (click)="openLink('www.twitter.com')">twitter</div>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <iframe [src]="link" *ngIf="link"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work really well! I will need to update my styling to make sure the iframe respects the size of the div. 

```
<iframe [src]="link" *ngIf="link" id="myIframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
    style="position: relative; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
```  

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kybqmc)

Answer (score 1):

Use an `iframe` instead of a div:

```
<iframe src="your-link-here"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is an Iframe. Since you tagged the question with Angular I'm going to assume you want to do it in Angular. Here is a related thread.
[enter link description here][1]

[How to set iframe src in Angular 2 without causing `unsafe value` exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037760/how-to-set-iframe-src-in-angular-2-without-causing-unsafe-value-exception/38037914)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're wanting to "embed" a webpage within that div, so to speak.

This can be accomplished using an [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp).

Place the iframe within your div, for example, to contain it to the positioning of that div.

```
<div>
  <iframe src="example"></iframe>
</div>
```