# How to set parameter in url in angular 6?

Tags: angular

> Blockquote

how to set the parameter in the URL?

My code as TS below

```
import { KlassaktUserService,KlassaktStorageService, KlassaktApiService } from '../../core';
import { KlassaktDashboardService, Student, listData } from '../../core/api/dashboard.sevice';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl} from '@angular/platform-browser';

declare var $: any;
@Component({ 
  selector: 'klassakt-photos',
  templateUrl: './photos.component.html' 
})
export class KlassaktPhotosComponent extends KlassaktDashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  }
  public loaderService: KlassaktLoaderService;

  async ngOnInit() {
    await super.ngOnInit();
  }
  public constructor(

    protected _dashboardService: KlassaktDashboardService,
    public _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {      
    let  selectedStudent = {
      schoolId: "134"
    }
    this.src = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`http://designs.mydeievents.com/jq-3d-flip-book/index.html?id=${selectedStudent.schoolId}`)
  }
  }
  public get students(): Student[]
  {
    return this._dashboardService.account.students;
  } 
}
```

this is my parameter which is found in the component.html file.

```
<p>Hi Arjun this is school Id {{selectedStudent.schoolId}}</p>
```

from ts file, I want to pass the same parameter 134 is my static school id

```
 schoolId: "134"
```

if I want to set dynamic parameter the code is below but not getting "param"

```
 param : number = this.selectedStudent.schoolId;
```

But i am not getting static or dynamic parameter in my project.

If I am using the below code working fine.

```
@Input()
      url: string = "https://arjunwalmiki.blogspot.com/";
      urlSafe: SafeResourceUrl;
     this.urlSafe = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);

    <iframe width="200px" height="300px" frameBorder="0" [src]="urlSafe"></iframe>
```

above code is working because of its parameterless call with a parameter not working.

Comment: @james thank you to edit my question

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works:

```
<iframe [src]="'http://designs.mydeievents.com/jq-3d-flip-book/index.html?id='+selectedStudent.schoolId"></iframe>
```

Comment: Dear All, Can anyone know solution this issue.

Comment: @ArjunWalmiki, did you put ' in your url? please copy and paste exactly my answer and see if it works

Comment: i try your solution for your refrence this is https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kizbtz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html try with id=134 but nothing is display any thing

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

TS:

`import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';`

```
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

   let  selectedStudent = {
      schoolId: "101"
    }
    this.src = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`http://designs.mydeievents.com/jq-3d-flip-book/index.html?id=${selectedStudent.schoolId}`)
  }
```

HTML

```
<iframe [src]="src"></iframe>
```

[Stackbiltz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kizbtz)

Comment: Nevermind, I thought that was inline in the HTML at first glance.

Comment: @kshetline FYI to make `src` a string you need wrap it single quote `"'src'"`

Comment: Definitely, @Karthick, I just misread the original reply and was thinking of something more like this: `<iframe src="http://designs.mydeievents.com/jq-3d-flip-book/index.html?id={{selectedStudent.schoolId}}">`, which should also work.

Comment: @kshetline This ain't work as `" "` tries to resolves the values between the quotes

Comment: @Ehsan i try <iframe [src]="'http://designs.mydeievents.com/jq-3d-flip-book/index.html?id='+selectedStudent.schoolId"></iframe> but not working.

Comment: @kshetline i try  <iframe src="http://designs.mydeievents.com/jq-3d-flip-book/index.html?id={{selectedStudent.schoolId}}"></iframe> not working

Comment: @AdritaSharma where in TS file  i have to write this code "src = `http://designs.mydeievents.com/jq-3d-flip-book/index.html?id=${selectedStudent.schoolId}`"

Comment: It's just a property, you can write it above the constructor

Comment: @AdritaSharma pls check is it correct :-@Component({
  selector: 'klassakt-photos',
  templateUrl: './photos.component.html' 
})
export class KlassaktPhotosComponent extends KlassaktDashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  src: any = 'http://designs.mydeievents.com/jq-3d-flip-book/index.html?id=${selectedStudent.schoolId}';
  FindLength: any;
  totalSecondd: any;
  corselimgcount: number = 0;
  tempcount: number = 0;
  previousval: number = 0;
 
  isipad: any;
  public isIPhone: boolean = false;
  public checkScreenSize() {
  this.isIPhone = true;
    this.isipad = true;
  }

Comment: What shall I check?

Comment: @Karthick, Angular interpolation does work inside quoted attribute values: https://stackblitz.com/edit/interpolation-inside-quotes

Comment: @ArjunWalmiki I have added a link

Comment: @AdritaSharma yes i try your solution with schoolid 134 but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Angular will sanitise the iframe url for you so you can't easily inject javascript into it, this is to protect you from XSS. 
There are workarounds in the following question.

[How to set iframe src in Angular 2 without causing `unsafe value` exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037760/how-to-set-iframe-src-in-angular-2-without-causing-unsafe-value-exception)

Answer (score -1):

This is my code after mix typescript ,jquery and html i found the solution.

```
 <a (click)="showDiv(selectedStudent.schoolId)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"> Arjun click here </a>


<!-- Modal -->

 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <!--<iframe id="myIframe" onload="delayedLoad()"></iframe>-->
                <div id="videoContainer">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
showDiv(pageid) {

    this.autoPlayVideo(pageid)
  }

  autoPlayVideo(vcode) {
    $("#videoContainer").html('<iframe width="200px" height="200px" src="http://designs.mydeievents.com/jq-3d-flip-book/index.html?id=' + vcode + '" ></iframe>');
    };
```

Thank you to all for your valuable time .spl thanks to @Adrita Sharma.