# Pass Iframe src value in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm tried to put a iframe inside Ionic page but with no success

the src comes from a json value

```
<iframe src="{{PostContent.link}}"></iframe>
```

I got an error

> ERROR Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context

Edit: I included my ts page
ts page

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiProvider } from '../../providers/api/api.service';
import {  ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


  postid: string;
PostContent:any = [];
  theInAppBrowser: any;

  constructor(
        public api:ApiProvider,
private route: ActivatedRoute,

  ) {

    this.postid = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

   }



   getPostContent(){


      this.api.get('doctor/' + this.postid  ).subscribe((data) => {
        this.PostContent = data;


        });


  }



 ngOnInit() {

    this.getPostContent();
}


}
```

Comment: any one facing the same?

Comment: you need to use DomSanitizer for iframe src. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037760/how-to-set-iframe-src-without-causing-unsafe-value-exception

Comment: I tried this but I cannot pass the url to the src attribute

Comment: can you share the code with your attempt? then it is easy to help you

Comment: You must need to use DomSanitizer for iframe src

Answer (score 0):

You should to use DomSanitizer for displaying that URL. This will enable you to create an exception for displaying the URL you want in the iFrame.

You can create a new variable and assign it the sanitized value, then display it in the HTML like this:

**Warning!** Using bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl might expose your page to XSS attacks. You should minimize and control this as much as possible. Check the documentation to ensure that you are protecting yourself properly when using DomSanitizer: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

**HTML**

```
<iframe [src]="sanitizedURL"></iframe>
```

**JS**

```
  //Wherever you are setting the URL, use DomSanitizer. For example:

      var URL = this.PostContent.link;

      // Use sanitizer for URL
      this.sanitizedURL = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(URL);
```

**Your JS full code, including new imports**

```
    import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { ApiProvider } from '../../providers/api/api.service';
    import {  ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

    //Import SafeResourceURL & DomSanitizer
    import { SafeResourceUrl, DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

  @Component({
    selector: 'iFrameComponent',
    templateUrl: './iFrameComponent.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./iFrameComponent.component.scss'],
  })

  export class iFrameComponent {

    //Declare URL variable
      sanitizedURL: SafeResourceUrl;

      postid: string;
     PostContent:any = [];
      theInAppBrowser: any;

      constructor(
            public api:ApiProvider,
            private route: ActivatedRoute,
            public domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,

      ) {

        this.postid = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

       }



       getPostContent(){


          this.api.get('doctor/' + this.postid  ).subscribe((data) => {
            this.PostContent = data;

              //Set URL
              var URL = this.PostContent.link;

              // Use sanitizer for URL
              this.sanitizedURL = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(URL);


            });


      }
```

Comment: Still the same error `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)`

Comment: Can you do console.log(this.PostContent.link) to get a sample URL your app is generating and share it here?

Comment: Try using this on your HTML <iframe [src]="sanitizedURL"> </iframe>

Comment: I know its very annoying, but just another new error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null`

Comment: Mmm this sounds like a different problem. Can you post the full error? I understand this is a build error, if you can paste the --verbose output it would be useful.

Comment: I think thats the dead end, I will use inAppbrowser instead of this headache, Thank you for your help .. I appreciate that so much

Comment: Good luck! Hope that solves it. Let me know if you try again ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DomSanitizer for iframe src
for that, you need to create a pipe using angular CLI

`ng generate pipe safe`

Open `safe.pipe.ts` file and paste code below:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

 public transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
            case 'html': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
            case 'style': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
            case 'script': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
            case 'url': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
            case 'resourceUrl': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
            default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
        }
  }
}
```

After that you just need to use safe pipe like this:

`<iframe src="{{PostContent.link | safe: 'url'}}"></iframe>`

Comment: Thank you guys alot , but still the same error `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)`

Comment: did you declare pipe in appmodule?

Comment: When you create a pipe first thing you should import that pipe in AppModule and declare that pipe in ngModule({
declaration: [

]
})

Comment: yes off course , but I notice that in the console I found `The pipe 'safe' could not be found`