# How to correctly sanitize an iframe url in Angular10?

Tags: angular, iframe, angular10

I ran into the issue of having to sanitize an url for an iframe in Angular, yet the accepted answer provided in [How to set <iframe src="..."> without causing `unsafe value` exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037760/how-to-set-iframe-src-without-causing-unsafe-value-exception) does not seem to work for me.

The error thrown is *ERROR Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context*

The solution I found is presented in the code below, seen in the comments [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26782)

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
  transform(url) {
    // commented return throws error, both with URL and with RESOURCE_URL. idk why
    // return this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL, url);
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL, url))
  }

}
```

The pipe is declared and exported in a shared module and used in an iframe tag (for now, I use a placeholder url from a youtube video)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SafePipe } from './pipes/safe.pipe';
@NgModule({

  declarations: [SafePipe],
  exports: [SafePipe],
})
export class SharedModule { };
```

html:

```
<iframe width="680" height="430" [src]="courseIframeUrl | safe" frameborder="0"
allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

My question is, is this correct? The accepted answer for the first link says that bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl is unsafe, yet [the documentation](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) calls for the method to be used for an iframe or for a script. How would a correct solution look like, if not?

Comment: Yes, this is fine assuming you always trust the `courseIframeUrl` value. Where it would become unsafe would be if you were allowing users to define what the value of `courseIframeUrl` is.