# ERROR Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have the following HTML code

```
<iframe #originalUrl [hidden]="!showOriginalDoc"  [src]="originalUrl"><span *ngIf="originalUrl===''">Original URL Not Available</span></iframe>
```

following angular code

```
 if(data.originalResearch.originalUrl===null)
  this.originalUrl='';
 else
  this.originalUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(data.originalResearch.originalUrl);
```

the above code still throws the following error :

CuratorModalBodyComponent.html:123 ERROR Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
    at DomSanitizerImpl.vendor../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser.es5.js.DomSanitizerImpl.sanitize (platform-browser.es5.js?ffb0:3992)
    at setElementProperty (core.es5.js?0445:9398)
    at checkAndUpdateElementValue (core.es5.js?0445:9318)
    at checkAndUpdateElementInline (core.es5.js?0445:9252)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js?0445:12357)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js?0445:12303)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js?0445:13167)
    at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (core.es5.js?0445:13146)

I am Using angular 4.4.1

Comment: Its working but throwing error at the same time which is not wanted

Answer (score 13):

Use iframe in this format:

```
<ifrmae [src]="variable_name">
```

In ts file:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private dom:DomSanitizer)
{ 
    variable_name=this.dom.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url); 
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you need to use the DomSanitizer to sanitize the src.

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private _sanitizationService: DomSanitizer){}
```

Wherever you need it pass the Src data to this funktion:

```
var imgSrc = this._sanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('data:image/png;base64,' + yourSrc);
```

Comment: even though they question didn't state they were dealing with a base64 string, I know I was... so I like that you added `'data:image/png;base64,'` in the argument of bypassSecurityTrustUrl.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your code. Your gave local template name to `iframe` and you are using the same name for property binding. Local template name have higher precedence so it `[src]="originalUrl"` will refer to `iframe`. You should change `#originalUrl` or remove it completely if it's not in use anywhere.

Comment: I changed to a different name, it's working but throwing the same error

Comment: Maybe you should return `originalUrl` from a function. look in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38269951/1533603)