# Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context in angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, observable

I am facing an issue in my angular 2 application where the data I save in service is not retrieved in component and then the view(not sure which one is the issue here). I am using an observable and subscribing to it. Below are my files.

Recipe.service.ts:

```
  @Injectable()
  export class RecipeService {
  constructor(private http: Http){}

  recipes : Array<Recipes> = new Array(20);

  getRecipes(): Observable<Recipes[]>{

    return this.http.get('my api here')
      .map(this.extractData.bind(this))
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();

    let total_no_of_recipes = body.pagination.count;
    let no_of_recipes;

    for(no_of_recipes = 0; no_of_recipes < total_no_of_recipes; no_of_recipes++) {
      this.recipes[no_of_recipes] = body.data[no_of_recipes].embed_url;
    }
    console.log(this.recipes); ---> Data is printed in console with no problem here
    return this.recipes;
  }

}
```

app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  observableRecipes: Observable<Recipes[]>;
  recipes: Recipes[];

  constructor(private recipeservice: RecipeService){}

  ngOnInit(){}

  onSubmit(){
    this.observableRecipes = this.recipeservice.getRecipes();
    this.observableRecipes.subscribe(
      recipes => { this.recipes = recipes }
    );
  }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<span>
    <a *ngFor="let recipe of recipes"> 
        {{ recipe.image }}    ---> error is from these two lines where I am accessing the value
        <iframe src="{{ recipe.image }}" style="width: 280px; height: 170px;"></iframe>
    </a>
</span>
```

Recipe.model.ts:

```
export class Recipes{
  public iamge: string;

  constructor(image: string){
    this.image = image;
  }
}
```

Can you please help as I am not able to understand why it is not receiving the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsafe value used in a resource URL context with Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927657/unsafe-value-used-in-a-resource-url-context-with-angular-2)

Comment: @match I tried the URL way, but it didn't work. Since, I am receiving an Observable from the service in the component(app.component.ts) I subscribed on to it. But I am not sure why it is not receiving data after it. Can you see any other issue here.

Comment: I think the main point from the answers there is you need to set `[src]="recipe.image"` not `src="{{recipe.image}}"`

Comment: I tried this. But it loads the whole page inside the <iframe>. Also, the value {{ recipe.image }} doesn't print anything in the statement above <iframe>.

Comment: Are you missing the '@Injectable()' notation before the service class?

Comment: No. I did include the '@Injectable'. Just didn't keep in here. Updated.

Comment: I don't see a definition for 'Recipes' used in the '*ngFor'

Comment: @Hany I changed it to "recipes" value which comes from this.observableRecipes.subscribe(
      recipes => { this.recipes = recipes }
    ); It still didn't work. Is this not a correct way?

Comment: Now enclose it by '<div *ngIf="recipes"></div> and retry

Comment: I did it. Still the same issue. <div *ngIf="recipes">
              <span *ngIf="afterSubmit">
                <a *ngFor="let recipe of recipes">
                  <p>{{ recipe.image }}</p>
                  <iframe src="{{ recipe.image }}" style="width: 280px; height: 170px;"></iframe>
                </a>
              </span>
            </div>

Comment: I modified code a bit to see whether array was retrieved in app.component.ts and the data does show up in console. Here is the code.        this.observableRecipes.subscribe(
      (recipes: Recipes)=> {
        if(recipes == null){
          this.statusMessage = 'gifs value is empty';
        } else {
          this.recipes = recipes;
          console.log(this.recipes);
        }
      });  I am not sure why it was not accessible in <a *ngFor="let recipe of recipes"> <p>{{ recipe.image }}</p><iframe src="{{ recipe.image }}" style="width: 280px; height: 170px;"></iframe></a>