# Angular Sanitization: File upload security

Tags: angular, xss, sanitization

I have a trivial case of file uploading.

**Usecase:**

1. User uploads images/videos/audio where internal url created from [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) is used in `<img/video/audio src="url">`.
2. User uploads other files (mime is not image/audio/video) that are passed directly to form-data upload to backend.

The issue is that angular doesn't like urls created as `URL.createObjectURL()` and goes on with `WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value blob:...` and adds `unsafe:` to each of them.

I am looking on other questions like [Unsafe value used in a resource URL context with Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927657/unsafe-value-used-in-a-resource-url-context-with-angular-2) which are all resolved by bypassing angular sanitization via `this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl()` however they mention nothing about security concerns.

**Why would angular sanitizer treat them as insecure?** I know what XSS is but don't have any background about possible attack vectors in a trivial case of using `URL.createObjectURL()` urls in something like `<img src=""/>`, in other words **are object URLs on img XSS exploitable?** or angular is just treating them as insecure to help protect us from carelessly/unintentionally injecting into any js-executable part of DOM?

Another thing is that once I change from object url to [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) data urls, sanitizer start complaining only on videos. I have found a similar issue(svg) at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18950 which seems like angular issue

Comment: Did you find an answer/solution for this?

Comment: I haven't .....

Comment: The potential danger is that it will miss such a blob: `const html = '<h1> Hello <script>alert(document.domain)<\/script></h1>';
const blob = new Blob([html], {type: 'text/html'});
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);`