# Angular 6 - Assign data to object tag dynamically based on url

Tags: angular

**Requirement**

To dynamically load the PDF file based on what user's have selected from list of PDF and show it in object tag / embed tag.

Users cannot download the PDF files, and hence object tag. However, other security settings are yet to be added.

**Issue**

I continuously get error "ERROR
Error: Required a safe ResourceURL, got a URL (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)" while trying to load PDF in object tag.

**Research**

I have already gone through several posts before coming and asking this question.

1. [Unsafe value used in a resource URL context with Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927657/unsafe-value-used-in-a-resource-url-context-with-angular-2/38079724)

**Reproducible steps**

I have created the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qqs3q2), and you can see the error being generated.

**Question**

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here?

I have tried several things including using safe-pipe from [Medium.com](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b)

Comment: Please read [ask]. It's not clear what, if anything, the problem is. Put a [mcve] **in the question**.

Comment: I have put the stackblitz link for it. And, it shows the error.

Comment: Again, *in the question*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)
```

[DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) categorizes various method depending on situations.

- `bypassSecurityTrustUrl`: Bypass security and trust the given value to be a safe style URL, i.e. a value that can be used in hyperlinks or `<img src>`.
- `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl`: Bypass security and trust the given value to be a safe resource URL, i.e. a location that may be used to load executable code from, like `<script src>`, or `<iframe src>`.

In this case, `object` tag embed multimedia content into HTML, so it is recognized as resource type

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This did the job for me. Can't believe I spent so long time and didn't realise I was using wrong function. Thanks