# data attribute of object tag in html is not updating the new url

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript

**Issue:**
I am trying to update the data attribute of object tag dynamically. 
The issue is the first time it loads perfectly, but thereafter it does not even though when i inspect the data attribute values are updated perfectly in html code using Angular. I believe it's not getting refreshed.

**Html Code:**

```
<object id="content" *ngIf="download" [data]="newUrl" width="70%" height="300px"></object>
```

**Angular Code:**

```
  updateUrl(url: string) {
    console.log('Parent Component updateUrl: ' + url);
    this.download = false; // hide

    this.newUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    document.getElementById("content").setAttribute('data', url);    
    this.download = true; // show 
  }
```

**What i Tried:**
Hide/Show before updating the url, but does not work.

Please note i cannot use jQuery. Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: have you try with [attr.data]="newUrl"?

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid pure javascript code inside the angular otherwise angular will not be the aware of changes. Make the below changes -

### html code

```
<object id="content" *ngIf="download" [attr.data]="newUrl" width="70%" height="300px"></object>
```

### Angular Code

```
 updateUrl(url: string) {
    console.log('Parent Component updateUrl: ' + url);
    this.download = false; // hide
    this.newUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url); 
    this.download = true; // show 
  }
```

### Demo

Woking copy is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-object-url-pdf

Comment: Make sure the pdf url is from the secured protocol `https`. Demo link is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-object-url-pdf

Comment: I am loading an external web page, currently it is not https. Also please note i cannot use iFrame.

Comment: @Dev, I don't think that will work. You might get a Mixed Content Error in that case since your website will load on HTTPS while your external webpage will load on http.

Comment: My website will not load on https, nor the iFrame links are https urls. Both are http.

Comment: Then it will work in your website however if you are testing this in any `https` site, it won't work.

Comment: Then it will work in your website however if you are testing this in any `https` site, it won't work.

Comment: Which environment or site you are checking in ?

Comment: local machine - stand alone application using angular

Comment: Can you try with this pdf https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf

Comment: Tried, it does load for the first time correctly but when you update it dynamically from code it doesn't update to the new url, even though after inspecting the code the new url is set. It is not getting refreshed i believe.

Answer (score 0):

update data attribute like this instead of updating using Javascript.

```
<object id="content" *ngIf="download" [attr.data]="newUrl" width="70%" height="300px"></object>
```

Comment: Tried the above, no change.

Comment: check this link.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927657/unsafe-value-used-in-a-resource-url-context-with-angular-2