# I need to include an iframe in angular and to bind a mongodb retrieved value as the src. How can I do that?

Tags: angular, iframe

Having an `iframe` like this:

```html
<iframe class="e2e-iframe-trusted-src"  height="480" width="500" src={{trailer.address}}> 
</iframe>
```

I'am getting the following error:

```
"ERROR Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context"
```

`nb:trailer.address` is retrieving the url.

Answer (score 0):

Angular has built-in value inspection for untrusted values - [Sanitization:  https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-and-security-contexts](https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-and-security-contexts)

Trusting safe values: https://angular.io/guide/security#bypass-security-apis

> Sometimes applications genuinely need to include executable code, display an `<iframe>` from some URL, or construct potentially dangerous URLs.

This seems to be exactly your case

You can't use the url retrieved from mongo directly - `trailer.address`. If you trust the content you can get a bypassed value which can be assigned to a `src`.

### Pipe Approach

Pipe

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safeUrl'
})
export class SafeUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
  transform(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```

Add to module

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, SafeUrlPipe ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
```

Usage in template

```html
<iframe class="e2e-iframe-trusted-src"  height="480" width="500" [src]="trailer.address | safeUrl"> 
</iframe>
```

### Component Approach

Component

```js
// Add the sanitizer service to your component
constructor(sanitizer) {
  this.sanitizer = sanitizer;
}

async fetchDataFromMongo() {
  const trailer = await fetchSomehow();
  // get a bypassed value, that won't trigger the error
  this.iframeUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(trailer.address);
}
```

Template

```html
<iframe class="e2e-iframe-trusted-src"  height="480" width="500" src="{{iframeUrl}}"> 
</iframe>
```

You can check the answers here for different approaches as they deal with the same issue: [<img>: Unsafe value used in a resource URL context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927657/img-unsafe-value-used-in-a-resource-url-context)

Comment: i cant really use this method because iam using loop in component.html like --*ngFor='let trailer of trailers'-- . Need to sanitize in template itself.

Comment: You can use the "Pipe Approach" to sanitize the value in the template.