# Display google maps in iframe dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, iframe

I would like to dynamically create a "google maps" link in javascript and than set it as src for my iframe, but I don't know if it is not possible with google maps, because this doesn't work:

```
    document.getElementById('map_canvas').src='http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=209246852521822593612.0004feda304ac527ea40a&amp;output=embed';
```

although, for example this works:

```
    document.getElementById('map_canvas').src='http://www.cnn.com';
```

This is my iframe:

```
<iframe id="map_canvas" name="map_canvas" width="100%" height="600px"
    frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
    src="">
</iframe>
```

Could you explain me, how is it possible to dynamically generate and display a google maps link in iframe ?

Thank you for help!

Comment: Why do you want to use an iframe? This is probably not what you really want, because there usually are better solutions.

Comment: I want to get my location using HTML 5 geolocation API and then center a map to my location, I know I could directly use Google Maps API, but I need to use iframe, because of placemarks in my map.

Comment: It is possible to add placemarks programmatically as well.
Use  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map_var_from_googlemapsMap,
        position: mapLocation,
        title: "works!"
    });

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388897/google-maps-inside-iframe-not-loading

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7898520/602554

Comment: @twicejr, yes it is, but if I add a placemark to my map in Google Maps(not programmatically), after click on placemark I get an infowindow with "directions", "save to my location", "search nearby", and I don't need to code it again, that's one of the reasons why I use iframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it this way:
I have added iframe per jQuery and set the desired src attr.

```
function displayMapAt(lat, lon, zoom) {
        $("#map")
                .html(
                        "<iframe id=\"map_frame\" "
                                + "width=\"100%\" height=\"600px\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" marginheight=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" "
                                + "src=\"https://www.google.sk/maps?f=q&amp;output=embed&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=sk&amp;geocode=&amp;q=https:%2F%2Fwww.google.sk%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fauthuser%3D0%26vps%3D5%26hl%3Dsk%26ie%3DUTF8%26oe%3DUTF8%26msa%3D0%26output%3Dkml%26msid%3D205427380680792264646.0004fe643d107ef29299a&amp;aq=&amp;sll=48.669026,19.699024&amp;sspn=4.418559,10.821533&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll="
                                + lat + "," + lon
                                + "&amp;spn=0.199154,0.399727&amp;t=m&amp;z="
                                + zoom + "\"" + "></iframe>");

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Google want you to access their maps in set ways.

If it's a classic map you want to embed on your website, go [here](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/72644?hl=en) and follow these simple instructions to get an embed code.

Or if you require more control try the [Google Maps Javascript API 3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/).
You can sign up for it for free, and use their tutorial and sample code to get it set up.

Answer (score 1):

Use the google maps embed api to embed within an iframe. You are on the right track, you just need a slightly different URL structure for your src.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/MODE?key=API_KEY&parameters
```

Where:

```
{MODE} is one of place, directions, search, or view, as described in the Modes section of this document.

{API_KEY} is your free API key.

Parameters include optional parameters, as well as mode-specific parameters.
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work even if I set iframe's src to google maps embed api link, because it doesn't display my placemarks from google maps.

Answer (score 1):

Solution without iframe:

In your javascript file add the following:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize&v=3.exp&sensor=false&language=nl'; //add you api key later
document.body.appendChild(script);

function initialize(element_id, lat, lng, zoom) 
{
    zoom || zoom = 10;

    var mapLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var mapOptions = 
    {
        center: mapLocation,
        zoom: zoom
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(element_id), mapOptions);
}
```

On demand use:

```
initialize('some_div_id', 52.56, 10.3);
```